# Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I want to use multiple private keys to connect to different servers or different portions of the same server (my uses are system administration of server, administration of Git, and normal Git usage within the same server). I tried simply stacking the keys in the `id_rsa` files to no avail.

Apparently a straightforward way to do this is to use the command

```
ssh -i <key location> login@server.example.com
```

That is quite cumbersome.

Any suggestions as to how to go about doing this a bit easier?

Comment: I wrote [this article](https://yayimorphology.org/ssh-identities-made-easy.html) that goes in depth on various configurations and their strength/shortcomings.

Answer (score 1593, accepted):

From my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host myshortname realname.example.com
    HostName realname.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/realname_rsa # private key for realname
    User remoteusername

Host myother realname2.example.org
    HostName realname2.example.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/realname2_rsa  # different private key for realname2
    User remoteusername
```

Then you can use the following to connect:

`ssh myshortname`

`ssh myother`

And so on.

Comment: This was a great help (in addition to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3828682/169153). If you want to use putty keys follow this document here: http://blog.padraigkitterick.com/2007/09/16/using-putty-ssh-keys-with-openssh-on-ubuntu

Comment: are there any other ways? Like an environment variable?

Comment: great answer.. one comment, in my case at least --- the private keys need to be in different folders. Don't exactly know why, but is the only way it works

Comment: Note that you can also specify multiple `IdentityFile` entries for the same `Host`, which are then tried in order when connecting.

Comment: Adding the comment `# private key for realname` can cause error `garbage at end of line; "#"`.

Comment: This howto youtube video nicely echoes @RandalSchwartz's answer and gives a more complete WSGWYG feel to his answer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9u4QPEMFK4A

Comment: This saved me a ton of hassle on my Windows box. Thanks! ssh-agent can suck it

Comment: If you are on windows, and your ssh client seems to be ignoring your .ssh/config file, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513712/git-ssh-client-for-windows-and-wrong-path-for-ssh-config-file

Comment: Use `IdentitiesOnly yes` to prevent ~/.ssh/id_rsa or any other identities.  (This was originally an edit)

Comment: And (just for comparision, like for/from github above) [here it is also confirmed, according to Bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/)

Comment: It is worth understanding, where this `~/ssh/config` [stuff is coming from](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/)

Comment: Note that if you are using an ssh-agent to hold your keys, IdentityFile in your config can point to the *public* key file.  That way, ssh can see that the file mentioned in the config is already present in the agent, which it wouldn't be able to do if the key was private (assuming you have a pass phrase on your private key).

Comment: Does this config file somehow get picked up by the `ssh` utility? Is that the default for which it looks?

Comment: As per the [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/139870/stop-ssh-client-from-offering-all-the-public-keys-it-can-find/421815) and the [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client#comment54751766_2419609) this will not actually stop you from offering the _wrong_ identity to github, and you need `IdentitiesOnly yes` also, in principle. (In fact the latter also does not work for me)

Comment: Sometimes you should not forget to execute `$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/realname2_rsa`

Answer (score 603):

You can instruct ssh to try multiple keys in succession when connecting. Here's how:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_old
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
# ... and so on

$ ssh server.example.com -v
....
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/example/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/example/.ssh/id_rsa_old
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
....
[server ~]$
```

This way you don't have to specify what key works with which server. It'll just use the first working key.

Also you would only enter a passphrase if a given server is willing to accept the key. As seen above ssh didn't try to ask for a password for `.ssh/id_rsa` even if it had one.

Surely it doesn't outbeat a per-server configuration as in other answers, but at least you won't have to add a configuration for all and every server you connect to!

Comment: This is a fantastic solution for the question asked, but didn't quite meet the needs that the asker intended.  For me, it was exactly the right solution and it perfectly meets the need for the "Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client".

Comment: This does not seem to work under the Host declaration in config file

Comment: This doesn't work well with git, as if you have two github deploy keys, the first one in the list is valid and will work, but then github will complain that the repository doesn't match.

Comment: This is a more dynamic approach, works great in certain situations. Thanks for this

Comment: If the SFTP/target server has security policies that lock the account (say after 3 multiple failed connection attempts), would this not end up locking the account. A connection is attempted, but with a 'wrong key' file

Comment: Be aware if you have something like fail2ban on those servers. You might end up in one of those jails... because of the failed attempts generated by the other keys...

Comment: @AdamReis For git one can use the `core.sshCommand` option instead (`ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1`)

Comment: if you have two github accounts, you will need different ssh keys for that and you can use the approach suggested here in your ssh config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751734/1764764

Comment: Best solution. I just removed the line `IdentitiesOnly yes` and added `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 311):

The previous answers have properly explained the way to create a configuration file to manage multiple ssh keys. I think, the important thing that also needs to be explained is the **replacement of a host name with an alias name while cloning the repository**.

Suppose, your **company's GitHub account's username is abc1234**.
And suppose your **personal GitHub account's username is jack1234**

And, suppose you have created two RSA keys, namely **id_rsa_company** and **id_rsa_personal**. So, your **configuration** file will look like below:

```
# Company account
Host company
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_company

# Personal account
Host personal
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

Now, when you are cloning the **repository** *(named demo)* from the company's GitHub account, the repository URL will be something like:

```
Repo URL: git@github.com:abc1234/demo.git
```

Now, while doing `git clone`, you should modify the above repository URL as:

```
git@company:abc1234/demo.git
```

**Notice how github.com is now replaced with the alias "company" as we have defined in the configuration file.**

Similary, you have to modify the clone URL of the repository in the personal account depending upon the alias provided in the configuration file.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once... this is the correct way to approach the issue, and it's safer and faster than other options. More scalable too (allows for defining different keys for the *same* hostname)

Comment: Great explanation! Works perfect for me. And if you forgot to clone the repo with the alias you can often edit the remote url of origin afterwards.

Comment: only pay attencion because config file must be (chmod 600)

Comment: I was recently setting up two different dev.azure.com repos when I needed separate keys for those and this answer is so much simpler and cleaner than others, awesome - much appreciated!

Comment: It's not stated explicitly, but this works around a major gotcha when trying to use multiple keys with GitHub: since you always log into GitHub as the same user `git`, any key that's saved on any GitHub account will allow for SSH login. But after the SSH login GitHub will then check if the key used is authorized for the specific action you're trying (e.g. checking out a repo), and that will fail if you have the wrong key. But the SSH part succeeded, so SSH will not try another key. This solution works around that by introducing host name aliases. Brilliant!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you use `ssh-agent`, then you should also add the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option to you config, otherwise `ssh-agent` will attempt connecting to a given alias with a key for a different alias if their hostnames match.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the repository url every time you clone a repo, you can have `Host company github.com` for one of the entries in the config file, which will behave as the 'default'.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Take care with docs as not everyone in the company is using the same alias.

Comment: you saved the day mate, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 277):

The [answer from Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client/2419609#2419609) almost helped me all the way.
I have a different username on the server, so I had to add the **User** keyword to my file:

```
Host           friendly-name
HostName       long.and.cumbersome.server.name
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/private_ssh_file
User           username-on-remote-machine
```

Now you can connect using the friendly-name:

```
ssh friendly-name
```

More keywords can be found on the [OpenSSH man page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config). **NOTE:** Some of the keywords listed might already be present in your */etc/ssh/ssh_config* file.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the user you usually specify directly in the url when connecting with user@host

Comment: I prefer to use the 'Port' keyword also. Another interesting keyword is 'StrictHostKeyChecking'.

Answer (score 118):

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/xxx_id_rsa
```

Make sure you test it before adding with:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/xxx_id_rsa username@example.com
```

If you have any problems with errors sometimes changing the security of the file helps:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/xxx_id_rsa
```

Comment: This is the most succinct and elegant solution in my opinion. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Bobo can you put it in your bashrc or bash_profile (or whatever is the mac equivalent)?

Comment: +1 for chmod 0600 - permissions issues were preventing me from connecting

Comment: Worked like a charm for me (and don't forget about 0600 perms).

Comment: Came from ubuntu on mac and this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: NB: Earlier, I created the config file recommended in the Randal Schwartz (accepted) answer. I had to delete that file for this to work. (Randal's answer didn't work for me, this one did after deleting that file)

Comment: Why do you need `ssh-add` when you'll be specifying the identity file using `ssh -i`?

Answer (score 107):

1. Generate an SSH key:

   ```
    $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C <email1@example.com>
   ```
2. Generate *another SSH key*:

   ```
    $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/accountB -C <email2@example.com>
   ```

   Now, two public keys (**id_rsa.pub**, **accountB.pub**) should be exists in the `~/.ssh/` directory.

   ```
    $ ls -l ~/.ssh     # see the files of '~/.ssh/' directory
   ```
3. Create configuration file `~/.ssh/config` with the following contents:

   ```
    $ nano ~/.ssh/config

    Host bitbucket.org
        User git
        Hostname bitbucket.org
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    Host bitbucket-accountB
        User git
        Hostname bitbucket.org
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/accountB
   ```
4. Clone from `default` account.

   ```
    $ git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git
   ```
5. Clone from the `accountB` account.

   ```
    $ git clone git@bitbucket-accountB:username/project.git
   ```

Note: Because of the `User git` directive, you can omit the `git@` portion of the repo URL, shortening your `clone` command like so:

```
    $ git clone bitbucket-accountB:username/project.git
```

This is the only purpose of that directive. If you don't need it (e.g. you always copy-paste the git clone command from the website), you can leave it out of the config.

[**See More Here**](https://github.com/sajibcse68/MyDailyLearn/blob/master/linux/shell-commands.md#manage-ssh-keys-for-multiple-accounts)

Comment: If you already have cloned repository you can change remote url: https://devconnected.com/how-to-change-git-remote-origin/

Answer (score 29):

I would agree with Tuomas about using ssh-agent. I also wanted to add a second private key for work and [this tutorial](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-6.html) worked like a charm for me.

Steps are as below:

1. `$ ssh-agent bash`
2. `$ ssh-add /path.to/private/key` e.g `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Verify by `$ ssh-add -l`
4. Test it with `$ssh -v <host url>` e.g `ssh -v git@assembla.com`

Comment: Having used `ssh-agent` for years, I've recently switched to using Gnome's `gnome-keyring` within my `i3` wm.  The reason is simple: Gnome's Keyring manager automagically handles adding and removing ssh keys without me having to remember to `ssh-add`.  In addition providing me with a single password to unlock them (and timeout on a specified time, for security). To each his own.  Since I use gnome settings on Arch, it was plug n play with my setup. If you are anti-gnome, ignore this comment.

Comment: @eduncan911, I agree that gnome-keyring can be helpful, but it doesn't really handle ed25519 keys, so that for me is a non-starter.  Update: I see from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Cannot_handle_ECDSA_and_Ed25519_keys that it now uses the system's ssh-agent so that's no longer a problem.

Comment: `ssh-agent bash` starts subsession. Also you can just evaluate the output of `ssh-agent -s` like ``eval `ssh-agent -s` ``. After that use `ssh-add`

Answer (score 26):

For me on MacOs, the only working solution was to simply add this in file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key3
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

`your_ssh_key` is without any extension. Don't use `.pub`.

Comment: Works but loads says "load pubkey "path/.ssh/key": invalid format"

Comment: This is something that has working for me and it's –a little bit– similar to yours: `$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` `$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/{private_key}` `$ git clone git@{alias}:{github_user}/{repo}.git` then on `~/.ssh/config` `Host github.com-{alias}` `HostName github.com` `PreferredAuthentications publickey` `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{private_key}` and on `{repo}/.git/config` `[remote "origin"]` `url = git@github.com-{alias}:{github_user}/{repo}.git` `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. 
  
[gist](https://gist.github.com/viniciusCamargo/b60677babe91ca65f7580a6c233334c9)

Comment: great! works for me in mac os

Answer (score 24):

Now, with the recent version of Git, we can specify **sshCommand** in the repository-specific Git configuration file:

```
  [core]
      repositoryformatversion = 0
      filemode = true
      bare = false
      logallrefupdates = true
      sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user
   [remote "origin"]
      url = git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: This is the most correct way to do it. If you don't want to fiddle in the file just run `git config --local core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_other_rsa_file"` in your git repository

Comment: Also consider this way as the most convenient one so far. Btw, @Canis, **--local** parameter is not really needed, it is default scope.

Answer (score 17):

I had run into this issue a while back, when I had two Bitbucket accounts and wanted to had to store separate SSH keys for both. This is what worked for me.

I created two separate ssh configurations as follows.

```
Host personal.bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile /Users/username/.ssh/personal
Host work.bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile /Users/username/.ssh/work
```

Now when I had to clone a repository from my work account - the command was as follows.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:teamname/project.git
```

I had to modify this command to:

```
git clone git@**work**.bitbucket.org:teamname/project.git
```

Similarly the clone command from my personal account had to be modified to

> git clone git@**personal**.bitbucket.org:name/personalproject.git

Refer [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution that I used inspired from [the answer of sajib-khan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135590/9885430). The default configuration is not set; it's my personal account on [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) and the other specified is my company account. Here is what I did:

#### Generate the SSH key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/company -C "name.surname@company.com"
```

#### Edit the SSH configuration

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

```
    Host company.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company
```

#### Delete the cached SSH key(s)

```
ssh-add -D
```

#### Test it!

```
ssh -T git@company.gitlab.com
```

> Welcome to GitLab, @hugo.sohm!

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

> Welcome to GitLab, @HugoSohm!

#### Use it!

Company account

```
git clone git@company.gitlab.com:group/project.git
```

Personal/default account

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:username/project.git
```

Here is the [source](https://coderwall.com/p/7smjkq/multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-accounts-on-github-or-gitlab) that I used.

Answer (score 8):

Use ssh-agent for your keys.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a configuration file named `config` in your `~/.ssh` folder. It can contain:

```
Host aws
    HostName *yourip*
    User *youruser*
    IdentityFile *idFile*
```

This will allow you to connect to machines like this

```
 ssh aws
```

Comment: What form does idFile take? An absolute path. Can you provide an example

Answer (score 3):

On [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) there is nothing to do.
Perhaps the same holds for newer version of Ubuntu or Debian systems.

After having created an second SSH key successfully the system will try to find a matching SSH key for each connection.

Just to be clear you can create a new key with these commands:

```
# Generate key make sure you give it a new name (id_rsa_server2)
ssh-keygen

# Make sure ssh agent is running
eval `ssh-agent`

# Add the new key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_server2

# Get the public key to add it to a remote system for authentication
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_server2.pub
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are working with [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) I would highly recommend working with [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html).

**Amazon EC2 Instance Connect provides a simple and secure way to connect to your instances using Secure Shell (SSH).**

**With EC2 Instance Connect, you use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies and principles to control SSH access to your instances, removing the need to share and manage SSH keys.**

After installing the relevant packages (`pip install ec2instanceconnectcli` or cloning the [repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-cli) directly) **you can connect very easy to multiple EC2 instances by just changing the instance id**:

[image]

---

**What is happening behind the scenes?**

When you connect to an instance using EC2 Instance Connect, the Instance Connect API pushes a one-time-use SSH public key to the instance metadata where it remains for 60 seconds. An IAM policy attached to your IAM user authorizes your IAM user to push the public key to the instance metadata.

The SSH daemon uses AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, which are configured when Instance Connect is installed, to look up the public key from the instance metadata for authentication, and connects you to the instance.

(*) Amazon Linux 2 2.0.20190618 or later and Ubuntu 20.04 or later comes preconfigured with EC2 Instance Connect.
For other supported Linux distributions, you must set up Instance Connect for every instance that will support using Instance Connect. This is a one-time requirement for each instance.

---

**Links:**

[Set up EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html)
[Connect using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ec2-instance-connect-connecting-ec2-cli)
[Securing your bastion hosts with Amazon EC2 Instance Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/securing-your-bastion-hosts-with-amazon-ec2-instance-connect/)

---

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [a Atlassian blog page](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/),
generate a *config* file within the *.ssh* folder, including the following text:

```
#user1 account
 Host bitbucket.org-user1
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user1
     IdentitiesOnly yes

 #user2 account
 Host bitbucket.org-user2
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then you can simply checkout with the suffix domain and within the projects you can configure the author names, etc. locally.

Comment: I used the same for GitHub without the `IdentitiesOnly yes` lines. It works.

Answer (score 2):

## Multiple key pairs on GitHub

1.0 SSH configuration file

1.1 *Create* ~/.ssh/config

1.2 chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config  (*must*)

1.3 Input the following into the file:

> Host pizza
>
> > HostName github.com
> >
> > PreferredAuthentications publickey # optional
> >
> > IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey1

Case A: Fresh new Git clone

Use this command to Git clone:

```
$ git clone git@pizza:yourgitusername/pizzahut_repo.git
```

Note: If you want to change the host name “pizza” of .ssh/config in the future, go into the Git cloned folder, edit .git/config file URL line (see case B)

Case B: Already have Git clone folder

2.1 Go to the cloned folder, and then go into the *.git* folder

2.2 Edit configuration file

2.3 Update the URL from *old to *new*:

```
(Old) URL = git@github.com:yourgitusername/pizzahut_repo.git

(New) URL = git@pizza:yourgitusername/pizzahut_repo.git
```

---

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT: You must start ssh-agent**

You must start ssh-agent (if it is not running already) before using ssh-add as follows:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` # start the agent

ssh-add id_rsa_2 # Where id_rsa_2 is your new private key file
```

Note that the eval command starts the agent on [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) on Windows. Other environments may use a variant to start the SSH agent.

Answer (score 1):

I love the approach to set the following in file ~/.ssh/config:

```
# Configuration for GitHub to support multiple GitHub  keys
Host  github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git

# UseKeychain adds each keys passphrase to the keychain so you
# don't have to enter the passphrase each time.
  UseKeychain yes

# AddKeysToAgent would add the key to the agent whenever it is
# used, which might lead to debugging confusion since then
# sometimes the one repository works and sometimes the
# other depending on which key is used first.
#  AddKeysToAgent yes

# I only use my private id file so all private
# repositories don't need the environment variable
# `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"` to be set.
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then in your repository you can create a `.env` file which contains the `ssh` command to be used:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_ssh_key"
```

If you then use e.g. [dotenv](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv) the environment environment variable is exported automatically and whoop whoop, you can specify the key you want per project/directory. The passphrase is asked for only once since it is added to the keychain.

This solution works perfectly with Git and is designed to work on a Mac (due to `UseKeychain`).

Comment: Works on windows as well. OpenSSH!

Answer (score 0):

On [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.5 running OpenSSH_5.3p1 and OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips, I solved the problem by renaming my key files so that none of them had the default name.

My .ssh directory contains id_rsa_foo and id_rsa_bar, but no id_rsa, etc.

Comment: And how does the keys get used? Is there any auto-detection?

Comment: See Randal Schwartz's answer for a way to select the correct key for a given host https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client/2419609#2419609

Comment: Yes, that makes it more explicit. Even using the `-i` option might result in something like `no such identity: /home/embo/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sshmulti) sshmulti npm package for maintaining multiple SSH keys.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend _not_ using npm for anything like this. It had a cascade of dependencies, which, on brief inspection, include a range of lone-wolf developers, several year old packages. The sshmulti npm page itself declares that it is untested.