# How to specify the private SSH-key to use when executing shell command on Git?

Tags: git, bash, shell, ssh

A rather unusual situation perhaps, but I want to specify a private SSH-key to use when executing a shell (`git`) command from the local computer.

Basically like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:TheUser/TheProject.git -key "/home/christoffer/ssh_keys/theuser"
```

Or even better (in Ruby):

```
with_key("/home/christoffer/ssh_keys/theuser") do
  sh("git clone git@github.com:TheUser/TheProject.git")
end
```

I have seen examples of connecting to a remote server with `Net::SSH` that uses a specified private key, but this is a local command. Is it possible?

Comment: See [this question in SuperUser](http://superuser.com/q/232373/90668) as well.

Comment: I'm wondering why this is so unusual that Git doesn't have an `-i` option like `ssh` does.

Comment: With git 2.10 (Q3 2016), you also have a new config: `git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i private_key_file'`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38474137/6309)

Comment: Is it really for one-time use ? If not one should associate host aliases and keys in ~/.ssh/config first. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067132/2637795)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794 here you can find a script with the solution

Comment: This is documented already: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH

Comment: I had to purge everything from my ssh agent before it would work because for some reason it kept picking up the old one no matter what. A reboot may also fix this I guess.

Answer (score 1132, accepted):

Something like this should work (suggested by orip):

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey; git clone git@github.com:user/project.git'
```

if you prefer subshells, you could try the following (though it is more fragile):

```
ssh-agent $(ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey; git clone git@github.com:user/project.git)
```

Git will invoke SSH which will find its agent by environment variable; this will, in turn, have the key loaded.

Alternatively, setting `HOME` may also do the trick, provided you are willing to setup a directory that contains only a `.ssh` directory as `HOME`; this may either contain an identity.pub, or a [config file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) setting IdentityFile.

Comment: But this will add the key permanently as an accepted SSH-key, right? I want to avoid that so that theuser2 can't mess with theuser's projects. It's for a web application so it's not practical to use different OS-users, which would have been the best option.

Comment: No, when git completes, ssh-agent terminates, and the key is forgotten.

Comment: this command does'not work on windows git bash. It says syntax error near unexpected token 'ssh-add'

Comment: Fixed command line (for windows or linux) would be something like: `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add sshkey; git clone url'`

Comment: This works fine on my desktop *nix machines, but fails on several servers that are virgin installs of current Debian. @HeyWatchThis's answer seems to work everywhere (although it's permanent where this one is temporary)

Comment: bash crashes on windows for me (using git bash environment variables). Is there a workaround for windows.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax of the first command line: it should be `$( ... )` to launch a subshell.

Comment: The `ssh-agent $(..)` syntax isn't working for me and I'm not sure how this is suppose to work: (ba)sh should execute the commands inside `$(..)` first, then run ssh-agent with the output as parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately instead of removing the key, it left it there.  You should add a ssh-add -d /path/to/key at the end.

Comment: The `$(..)` syntax probably doesn't do what you expect: it runs the commands inside first and sends their output to `ssh-agent`.  This might happen to work anyway if another `ssh-agent` happens to be already running, but then the new key will be left in the agent (unless you add `ssh-add -d` to take it out) and the answer becomes `ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey && git clone git@github.com:user/project.git ; ssh-add -d /somewhere/yourkey` (and we assume `ssh-agent` is already running, and note the use of `&&` rather than `;`).  But that's moot because the `bash -c` version is correct.

Comment: This solution stopped working for me for some reason after I upgraded from OpenSUSE 42.3 to 15.0. I switched to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754018/47680, which is working well.

Comment: You also accomplish this with `ssh-add -t 60; git clone git@github.com:user/project.git`. That will just expire the key after 60 seconds.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 for quite some time, but in the past week it's stopped working and I can't seem to pinpoint the change. Infact it fails to work on two separate systems. The ssh-agent service despite running, reports nothing though running with `-d` generates a `cannot create agent root reg key, ERROR:5` error.

Comment: And then do `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i /path/to/key"` so that it remembers your key every time you do a git fetch / git pull

Answer (score 1676):

None of these solutions worked for me.

Instead, I elaborate on @Martin v. Löwis  's mention of setting a `config` file for SSH.

SSH will look for the user's `~/.ssh/config` file. I have mine setup as:

```
Host gitserv
    Hostname remote.server.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
    IdentitiesOnly yes # see NOTES below
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

And I add a remote git repository:

```
git remote add origin git@gitserv:myrepo.git
```

(or clone a fresh copy of the repo with `git@gitserv:myrepo.git` as address)

And then git commands work normally for me.

```
git push -v origin master
```

If you have submodules, you can also execute the following in the repo directory, to force the submodules to use the same key:

```
git config url.git@gitserv:.insteadOf https://remote.server.com
```

**NOTES**

- The `IdentitiesOnly yes` is required to [prevent the SSH default behavior](https://serverfault.com/questions/450796/how-could-i-stop-ssh-offering-a-wrong-key/450807#450807) of sending the identity file matching the default filename for each protocol. If you have a file named `~/.ssh/id_rsa` that will get tried BEFORE your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.github` without this option.
- `AddKeysToAgent yes` lets you avoid reentering the key passphrase every time.
- You can also add `User git` to avoid writing `git@` every time.

**References**

- [Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client)
- [How could I stop ssh offering a wrong key](https://serverfault.com/questions/450796/how-could-i-stop-ssh-offering-a-wrong-key/450807#450807)

Comment: I found that when you specify multiple keys using .ssh/config, you need to use host friend name in line "Host" as part of "git remote add" command.  If line is "Host stg", then you need to use git remote add <someName> user@stg:/path_to_git_repo.git ". If you use exact server name like user@myserver.com:/path_to_git_repo.git, the config file is not picked by git. Hence, it is not picking private key file correctly.  I tried this by pushing same content to github and heroku and works only when you give friendly name in "git remote add"

Comment: I wasn't sure about the Host for github. I found this link: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996.

Comment: @JonnyReeves edits introduced mismatched hostnames. Pushing to `gitserv` will not match the ssh config `Host` entry for `remote` or `remote.server.com`. Therefore the intended `IdentityFile` will not be used. I'm going to edit this answer.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) if you want to have few key files for few git repositories

Comment: I don't understand why `IdentitiesOnly` is necessary. As I understand it, by adding this host to the config file, it will add this ssh key to a list of keys that it will try, i.e. it will first try  `~/.ssh/identity`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then it will try `~/.ssh/id_rsa.github`. Is there anything wrong with it trying `id_rsa` before `id_rsa.github`, as long as it eventually tries `id_rsa.github`?

Comment: Umm this doesn't work for me. When I do a git pull from my private repo, git ignores my `.ssh/config` file completely and tries id_rsa instead, which is the wrong key.

Comment: I had all of this except for `IdentitiesOnly` and it worked for a while but then one day stopped working and was trying to use my default key in `id_rsa`. `IdentifiesOnly` does seem to be important.

Comment: You could use `Host remote.server.com` and keep using the original URL

Comment: For some reason, this worked for me, but I add to SSH-login to the Git server first for the identifyFile to be used (Probably has to do with the known_hosts not being populated). So, after doing that, and before running your `git clone ...` command, run:
`ssh {hostname}`

Comment: Also User may be required in the config entry

Comment: This worked for me after two changes. If the config file is new, don't forget to do `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use)). And if you are using GitHub, replace `Host gitserv` with `Host github.com`, omit `Hostname remote.server.com`, and add remote with `git remote add origin git@github.com:user_name/repo_name.git`.

Comment: To save some more characters, add `User git` into that configuration item and just use `gitserv:myrepo.git` as remote URL.

Comment: This is the only answer that also works with Windows if you are using the ssh client that comes with Git (located at `%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` by default).  Modify or create the `config` file located at `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`.

Comment: I needed to use `Host` instead of `Hostname`. I.e. `Host xfce.org\nHost gitlab.xfce.org`

Comment: github: HostName github.com User git (answered by Karsten), gitlab: HostName gitlab.com User git

Comment: it looks like the comment makes it fail:

/root/.ssh/config line 4: garbage at end of line; "#".

so if this is the case, remove the comment

Comment: I've took liberty to add a solution for submodules.

Answer (score 911):

Starting from Git 2.3.0 we also have the simple command (no config file needed):

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' git clone user@host:repo.git
```

Note the `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` is required to prevent the SSH default behavior of sending the identity file matching the default filename for each protocol as noted in the answer above.

Comment: I get `cannot run ssh -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/git: No such file or directory` though it exists `444 Nov 16 18:12 /home/vagrant/.ssh/git` from `ls -l /home/vagrant/.ssh/git`

Comment: @ted: chmod 400 /home/vagrant/.ssh/git

Comment: Nice and easy solution. I suggest creating an alias if you need to do this a lot.

Comment: @ted Read [What permissions levels should I give to the private key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9270734) if confused.

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod 400 <path-to-private-key-file>`. Otherwise git command may fail with no special error message...

Comment: This worked for me using Git 2.13.6 on Mac. I was able to clone a remote repo over a SSH forward proxy. Thanks!

Note: I only had to `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file'` though.

Comment: Please note that also .ssh folder has to be granted permissions, besides the subfolder as mentioned above... so be sure to run `chmod 400 path/to/.ssh` too...

Comment: It would be good if this answer also included `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` to make sure that the key specified with `-i` gets used (as opposed to a key from SSH agent).

Comment: To do this from within PowerShell: `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'; git clone user@host:repo.git`

Comment: Yea alias is nice, ```alias GIT="GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' git"```, and then e.g. ```GIT push```

Comment: If you have identities specified in your `~/.ssh/config` file that you want to ignore, you will also need to add `-F /dev/null` to the `ssh` command.

Comment: For those looking for a per repo config, you can add this to the `core.sshCommand` config option for your repo.  Note that the path to the identity file should resolve from the repo as your directory, so typically it should be something like `~/.ssh/identity_file`.

Comment: If you're on Windows WSL you might need a sudo if permissions are too open, so like this: `sudo GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /mnt/c/Users/dome/path/to/mykey -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' git push git@github.com:do-me/SemanticFinder.git`.

Comment: This one works well when you have multiple ssh binaries, and the ssh-agent loaded into memory is using the wrong binary you need. (FIPS requirements etc.)

Answer (score 538):

Other people's suggestions about `~/.ssh/config` are extra complicated. It can be as simple as:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

Comment: You need the `IdentitiesOnly` option, too.

Comment: @EnzeChi you can have multiple github accounts by manipulating the remotes:  `git remote add ssh://personal/org/proj.git && git remote add ssh://corporate/org/proj.git`.  Then you config looks like `Host personal HostName github.com ... Host corporate HostName github.com`

Comment: Mine works without the `IdentitiesOnly` option. Can someone explain why this should be required?

Comment: Not exactly fitting granularity. My company has an organisation on github and I have a personal account on github, so with just the host it does not work nicely.

Comment: Is there a difference between `Host *.github.com` and `Host github.com`?

Comment: @anydoby you can make custom hosts: `Host mypersonalgithub // HostName github.com // IdentityFIle personalgithub_ed25519` and `Host companygithub // HostName github.com // IdentityFIle company_ed25519`

Comment: @AlbinoDrought it likely works because the host doesn't care how many keys you try. Some hosts reject the connection after a certain number of failed keys.

Comment: @minseong I have not had issues with *.github.com until today after months of it working fine. I did add more entries in my config file but should have been unrelated. After removing the `*.` it started working immediately

Answer (score 397):

With git 2.10+ (Q3 2016: released Sept. 2d, 2016), you have the possibility to set a *config* for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (and not just an environment variable as described in [Rober Jack Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676427/robert-jack-will)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754018/6309))

See [commit 3c8ede3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c8ede3ff312134e84d1b23a309cd7d2a7c98e9c) (26 Jun 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc21164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc21164e66e39670931d3270f8db4c0ed0e0b816), 19 Jul 2016)</sup>

> A new configuration variable `core.sshCommand` has been added to
> specify what value for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to use per repository.
>
> ```
> core.sshCommand:
> ```
>
> If this variable is set, `git fetch` and `git push` will use the specified command instead of `ssh` when they need to connect to a remote system.
> The command is in the same form as the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable and is overridden when the environment variable is set.

It means the `git pull` can be:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo/already/cloned
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i private_key_file' 
# later on
git pull
```

---

When cloning a new repo, where there is not yet any `.git/config` to modify, can first set it for just one command like `git clone` or `git submodule add`:

```
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i private_key_file" clone host:repo.git
```

Once the repo exists you can set the option permanently in the `.git/config`:

```
cd <repo or submodule you just cloned>
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i private_key_file"
```

This is easier than setting a `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable, which, on Windows, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625578/6309) by [Mátyás Kuti-Kreszács](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10671021/m%C3%A1ty%C3%A1s-kuti-kresz%C3%A1cs), would be

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i private_key_file"
```

---

For all those commands, you can add a `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` to limit SSH to the the private/public key you are specifying:

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' 
# or
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes" clone host:repo.git
# or
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes"
```

---

[gsullins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763086/gsullins) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git/38474137?noredirect=1#comment132149969_38474137) to adds to the `.zshrc` the following alias:

```
alias git.key1="git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i <absolute path to private key>'"
```

---

As noted by [Jaredo Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7859025/jaredo-mills) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git/38474137#comment135893120_38474137):

> One pitfall: if you mirror your repo to more than one host (Github, Gitlab), with different private keys, this method will send the wrong key.
> The key is not associated with the repo, but with a username and hostname. `~/.ssh/config` is the right place to get the association right, and it has the right matching capabilities for the job (see [`man ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)).

See [HeyWatchThis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472876/heywatchthis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/6309) for illustration.

Comment: Works. Folks should consider this the best answer. Once issued, it can be informative to diff the .git/config file with a version copied to /tmp beforehand. A new entry has been created: sshCommand = ...  For what it's worth, I used 'git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/privatekeyfile".

Comment: Only works with an existing git directory. Otherwise you need to set it globally which isn't really what you want.

Comment: @Spanky You can do the inline command `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i private_key_file" clone host:repo.git` followed by the config set `git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i private_key_file' `

Comment: This works great thank you. Had to workaround another issue on Windows, if you are using the native Windows ssh and the Windows ssh-agent service you will need to specify the path to the windows ssh otherwise it will use the ssh shipped with git and you'll have to type the password in every time.

```git config core.sshCommand 'C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe -i C:/Users/firstname.lastname/.ssh/mygitkey_ed25519 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes'
```

Comment: @holytshirt True. I always set the PATH to reference the ssh I want (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` in my case). That way, no full path to specify.

Comment: @Johntron The `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` is not *mandatory* but can help limit SSH to use only the specified private key instead of falling back to other possible authentication mechnism.

Answer (score 165):

Contents of my_git_ssh_wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -i /path/to/ssh/secret/key $1 $2
```

Then you can use the key by doing:

```
GIT_SSH=my_git_ssh_wrapper git clone git@github.com:TheUser/TheProject.git
```

Comment: Nice solution. You can also simplify this with > GIT_SSH=my_git_ssh_wrapper; git clone git@github.com:TheUser/TheProject.git

Comment: This solution also covers situations when you want to use git from account without home directory.

Comment: Fantastic. You can use this way to private servers too:
`GIT_SSH="git_wrapper" git clone ssh://user@server/path/to/project"`

Comment: Don't forget to add executable permissions to script to avoid "Permission denied" error

Comment: After cloning with this wrapper, you can set the wrapping command inside this particular project's git config `cd projectname ; git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i private_key_file -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' `, and then you wont need to use wrapper for subsequent pulls

Answer (score 160):

To sum up answers and [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby#comment30939882_12681691), the best way to set up git to use different key files and then forget about it, which also supports different users for the same host (e.g. a personal GitHub account and a work one), which works on Windows as well, is to edit `~/.ssh/config` (or `c:\Users\<your user>\.ssh\config`) and specify multiple identities:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
IdentityFile /path/to/your/personal/github/private/key
User dandv

Host github-work
HostName github.com
IdentityFile /path/to/your/work/github/private/key
User workuser
```

Then, to clone a project as your personal user, just run the regular `git clone` command.

To clone the repo as the `workuser`, run `git clone git@github-work:company/project.git`.

Comment: I downvoted you because everything you say is already covered in the answers above, and in my eyes, even more clearly.  For instance, why exactly do you define the User to e dandv and workuser, respectively?

Comment: You answered a 4 year old question with no new informations and you are claiming that your answer is "the best way". Moreover you downvoted and hassled other users to remove their answer ... just to get your one pushed up.

Comment: @hroptatyr: I've used `dandv` and `workuser` to support my example, "e.g. a personal GitHub account and a work one". `dandv` is my GitHub username.

Comment: You've actually got the right idea here, but this won't work.  You have to use user 'git'.  The problem is, you're duplicating thamster's reply from 2012.

Comment: I like this answer. However, for me this only works if I add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to my ssh config file.

Comment: the problem with any solution that has you creating duplicate host entries with different aliases are two: 1. you need to remember them 2. some tooling will infer the http web interface of the remote from the ssh remote, this breaks it.

Answer (score 111):

The problem is when you have **different remote repositories on the same host** (say github.com), and you want to interact with them using **different ssh keys** (i.e. different GitHub accounts).

In order to do that:

1. First you should declare your different keys in `~/.ssh/config` file.

   ```
   # Key for usual repositories on github.com
   Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   # Key for a particular repository on github.com
   Host XXX
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_other_rsa
   ```

   By doing this you associate the second key with a new friendly name "XXX" for github.com.
2. Then you must change the remote origin of your particular repository, so that it uses the friendly name you've just defined.

   Go to your local repository folder within a command prompt, and display the current remote origin:

   ```
   >git remote -v
   origin  git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git (fetch)
   origin  git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git (push)
   ```

   Then change origin with:

   ```
   >git remote set-url origin git@XXX:myuser/myrepo.git
   >git remote -v
   origin  git@XXX:myuser/myrepo.git (fetch)
   origin  git@XXX:myuser/myrepo.git (push)
   ```

   Now you can push, fetch... with the right key automatically.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't get it working. Whenever I run a `git` command I get: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname helloworld-wp-github: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Did you add a new entry in your ~/.ssh/config ? This is how you tell ssh that your "helloworld-wp-github" is an alias for "github.com". Then, and only then, you can use your alias as remote server in git commands.

Comment: Adding `User git` was what I was missing. You can test connection with `ssh -vT XXX` ( https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey )

Comment: this is a horrible answer to be honest. you now have to remember all these special domain names and any tooling that relies on the git remote being correctly transferrable to a http web interface is now broken. what's that somerandomproject.github.com doesn't exist? oh no? dramalama!

The correct solution is to use the core.sshCommand, bonus points if you persist it with your ~/.dotfiles/.gitconfig and make use of includeif logic 

Answer (score 99):

As stated here: https://superuser.com/a/912281/607049

You can configure it per-repo:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null"
git pull
git push
```

Comment: What does `-F /dev/null` do? As far as I can see this will change configFile from the `~/.ssh/config` default but why is that desired? To ensure a sandboxed command?

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html, specifies no config file, so when git will run ssh, no config file will be passed (in fact it's a kind of sandbox mode, just ignore user config default options) Original thread in superuser has more info about -F

Comment: Why would you put this in your `.bash_profile` as an alias? You just run it once (for each repo). In general, use functions instead of aliases and your life will be easier; but both are slightly hard if you are confused about quoting.

Comment: git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/{key}" clone {repo}

Answer (score 68):

The fastest and simplest way of doing it is by:

Clone your repo with ssh:

`git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your_key>" clone git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git`

then `cd` into you cloned repo and:

`git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your_key>'`

To test it's working:

`git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git pull`

So you may wonder: **why my created ssh key does not work** after I planted the .pub in github and the private is in the default directory?

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) gives us a command that clarifies the issue:
`ssh -vT git@github.com`

The output *shows a list of ssh keys names git looks for*. So, you may want to create your key with one of those names, or use the above process to include the one you need.

Comment: To add to this, you should be configuring this by using another feature of gitconfig: includeif.

Comment: You can replace the two commands with this one command: `git clone -c "core.sshCommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your_key>" git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git` . Notice the `-c` option comes after `clone`, not before.

Comment: `-i` is merely a suggestion without further flags. To avoid this heresy, expand it to `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/<your_key> --identity_file=~/.ssh/<your_key>`.

Answer (score 49):

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/git-private-access-key" git clone $git_repo
```

or

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/git-private-access-key"
git clone REPO
git push
```

Comment: That is clean. I want to add `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/git-private-access-key" git clone repo` if anyone want to use it temporarily.

Answer (score 42):

Way better idea to add that host or ip to the `.ssh/config` file like so:

```
Host (a space separated list of made up aliases you want to use for the host)
    User git
    Hostname (ip or hostname of git server)
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_(the key you want for this repo)
```

Comment: That's useful, but makes you use the repo key for all interaction with that hostname. If there are other repos on the same server that require different keys, using a wrapper and telling git to use it with GIT_SSH is better.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I use multiple keys for Github - one for work and one for my personal account. You don't have to put a domain name for "Host". You can put any kind of alias you want. For example, I use gh-home and gh-work as my hostnames and when I clone I use, for example, `git clone git@gh-work:repo/project.git`

In my ~/.ssh/config I have two sections that both use github.com for HostName. They just have different IdentityFile and Host

Comment: @brettof86 this strategy works for the most part, but what do you do when a repository you are checking out depends on a gem which is also hosted on github? The the reference to the github repo in the Gemfile wont contain your "alias", well not unless you want to break things for other developers on the project...

Comment: The gist is here https://gist.github.com/justbrettjones/5f9940effeba9f36daa6#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 42):

**From Git version 2.10.0, you can configure this per repo or globally**

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'"
```

This will specify for the current repo what ssh key will use. I assume if you want to specify this global only need to set the `--global` option.

Comment: How do I specify this for checkout? I mean, I've just created a new empty folder, opened console, went inside this folder and executed this command. It tells me: `fatal: not in a git directory`.

Comment: You need to initialize git, with git init

Comment: Using __WSL2__ I had originally set the path using standard forward-slashes ``\`` including the `C:\Users` path but had to alter it verbatim as you had it with the standard Unix path syntax `~/`. This worked perfectly for my and especially helpful with the note about setting the `--global` option which was all but implied for most cases

Answer (score 37):

This command clones the repo and configures the SSH key to use permanently:

```
git clone -c "core.sshCommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/<key>" git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

Now, if you run `git fetch`, `git pull`, or `git push`, it will use the SSH key configured in `core.sshCommand` (saved in `.git/config`).

Answer (score 33):

I went with the GIT_SSH environment variable.
Here's my wrapper, similar to that from Joe Block from above, but handles any amount of arguments.

File ~/gitwrap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i ~/.ssh/gitkey_rsa "$@"
```

Then, in my .bashrc, add the following:

```
export GIT_SSH=~/gitwrap.sh
```

Comment: I did set this on .bashrc. But when I login to openshift instance, it does not seems to be calling it. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It fails with an error for me.. its not able to find the script event though its there.. not sure whats going on...error: cannot run /tmp/gitwrap.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: If you face "No such file or directory" error, put full path of `gitwrap.sh`, for example `/home/ubuntu/gitwrap.sh`

Comment: you might want to add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the ssh command

Comment: I tried to implement this, but I was not happy with the fact that I needed an extra script file to act as a wrapper, and when I checked the documentation, I found an easier way. You can use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to specify the command you want git to use. In my case (different private key), I had to do this: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_alternative_private_key"` and then continue to use git as normal in the script.

Answer (score 19):

If none of the other solutions here work for you, and you have created multiple ssh-keys, but still cannot do simple things like

```
git pull
```

then assuming you have two ssh key files like

```
id_rsa
id_rsa_other_key
```

then inside of the git repo, try:

```
# Run these commands INSIDE your git directory
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_other_key
```

and also make sure your github default username and userid are correct by:

```
# Run these commands INSIDE your git directory
git config user.name "Mona Lisa"
git config user.email "mona.lisa@email.com"
```

See https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996 for more more information.

Comment: Note if you get `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`, try `$ eval \`ssh-agent -s\``, and try again.

Comment: Why do you think it matters in which directory you run `ssh-add`?

Comment: @BenCartwright Because you are modifying local settings, not global settings. This approach modifies `.git` inside the repo not the git program globally.  You can use `--global` to set global username and email.

Answer (score 19):

### 2021.  If you're on a Mac.

Say you have an ubuntu server on aws, which you normally connect to like this:

```
% ssh -i blah/yourkeypair.pem ubuntu@test.fattie.com
```

In terminal just

```
% export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /Users/fattie/Desktop/blah/yourkeypair.pem"
```

After you have done that. You can then freely ...

```
% git clone ubuntu@test.fattie.com:/home/ubuntu/teste.git
```

That will clone the repo on your server to your local folder "teste",

you can then freely when in teste/ do the usual commands such as ...

```
% git push origin master
```

and so on.

--

Note also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287133/294884

---

As for on the server, it seems you basically

```
] git clone --bare the-actual-folder teste.git
```

and then in teste.git

```
] git init --bare --shared
```

Answer (score 16):

I just needed to add the key and then rerun the git clone.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mynewkey
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
git clone git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git
```

Comment: Thank you! After doing the ssh-add i got an error about the agent and then I found this answer which helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77364320/4484799

Answer (score 14):

When you need to connect to github with a normal request (`git pull origin master`), setting the Host as `*` in `~/.ssh/config` worked for me, any other Host (say, "github" or "gb") wasn't working.

```
Host *
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx
```

Comment: Might as well leave the entire "Host *" line out then.

Comment: It probably wasn't working because it didn't match your remote URL. If you want to use `Host my-host-alias`, you have to set `remote.origin.url=git@my-host-alias:[username]/[repo].git`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't have a config file and I kept getting `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` error and making new keys didn't help.

Answer (score 14):

Many of these solutions looked enticing. However, I found the generic git-wrapping-script approach at the following link to be the most useful:

[How to Specify an ssh Key File with the `git` command](https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command)

The point being that there is no `git` command such as the following:

```
git -i ~/.ssh/thatuserkey.pem clone thatuser@myserver.com:/git/repo.git
```

Alvin's solution is to use a well-defined bash-wrapper script that fills this gap:

```
git.sh -i ~/.ssh/thatuserkey.pem clone thatuser@myserver.com:/git/repo.git
```

Where `git.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The MIT License (MIT)
# Copyright (c) 2013 Alvin Abad
# https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Git wrapper script that can specify an ssh-key file
Usage:
    git.sh -i ssh-key-file git-command
    "
    exit 1
fi

# remove temporary file on exit
trap 'rm -f /tmp/.git_ssh.$$' 0

if [ "$1" = "-i" ]; then
    SSH_KEY=$2; shift; shift
    echo "ssh -i $SSH_KEY \$@" > /tmp/.git_ssh.$$
    chmod +x /tmp/.git_ssh.$$
    export GIT_SSH=/tmp/.git_ssh.$$
fi

# in case the git command is repeated
[ "$1" = "git" ] && shift

# Run the git command
git "$@"
```

I can verify that this solved a problem I was having with user/key recognition for a remote bitbucket repo with `git remote update`, `git pull`, and `git clone`; all of which now work fine in a `cron` job script that was otherwise having trouble navigating the limited-shell. I was also able to call this script from within R and still solve the exact same `cron` execute problem
(e.g. `system("bash git.sh -i ~/.ssh/thatuserkey.pem pull")`).

Not that R is the same as Ruby, but if R can do it... O:-)

Comment: Apart from the syntax, how is this better than `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/thatuserkey.pem" git clone clone thatuser@myserver.com:/git/repo.git` as per [Robert Jack Will's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29754018/27358)?

Answer (score 13):

A lot of good answers, but some of them assume prior administration knowledge.

I think it is important to explicitly emphasize that **if you started your project by cloning the web URL**
- `https://github.com/<user-name>/<project-name>.git` 
then you need to **make sure that** the `url` **value** under `[remote "origin"]` in the `.git/config` **was changed to the SSH URL** (see code block below).

With addition to that make sure that you add the `sshCommmand` as mentioned below:

```
user@workstation:~/workspace/project-name/.git$ cat config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/location-of/.ssh/private_key -F /dev/null <--Check that this command exist
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:<user-name>/<project-name>.git  <-- Make sure its the SSH URL and not the WEB URL
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Read more about it [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use).

Comment: Solid answer, provides info for project level config instead of system wide config. Other answers seem to ignore that you basically only run into this problem if you don't have a system wide configuration!

Answer (score 9):

if you have directory on your path where you want to sign with a given identifyfile you can specify to use a specific identify file via the .ssh/config file by setting the [`ControlPath`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) e.g.:

```
host github.com
  ControlPath ~/Projects/work/**
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
  User git
```

Then `ssh` will use the specified identity file when doing git commands under the given work path.

Comment: Found out later that you can also set the properties `ControlMaster auto` and `ControlPersist yes`, so that you do not need to retype the password every time. Found the info in this [article](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/speeding-up-ssh-session-creation/)

Comment: ControlPath
Specify the path to the control socket used for connection sharing as described in the ControlMaster section above or the string ''none'' to disable connection sharing. In the path, '%l' will be substituted by the local host name, '%h' will be substituted by the target host name, '%p' the port, and '%r' by the remote login username. It is recommended that any ControlPath used for opportunistic connection sharing include at least %h, %p, and %r. This ensures that shared connections are uniquely identified.

Comment: actually this sounds like an unintentional side effect of the proper use of ControlPath

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just add location of identity key to git config file  for a particular repo like this:

```
cd .git

vi config

[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i <IDENTITY_KEY_LOCATION> -o IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Is this in the repo? How do you then clone it in the first place? How does it work when others clone it, or I use a different machine?

Comment: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i <IDENTITY_KEY_LOCATION> -o IdentitiesOnly=yes" git clone …` and then this answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows with Git Bash you can use the following to add a repository

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add "key-address"; git remote add origin "rep-address"'
```

for example:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /d/test/PrivateKey.ppk; git remote add origin git@git.test.com:test/test.git'
```

Which private key is in drive D, folder test of computer. Also if you want to clone a repository, you can change `git remote add origin` with `git clone`.

After enter this to Git Bash, it will ask you for passphrase!

Be Aware that openssh private key and putty private key are different!

If you have created your keys with puttygen, you must convert your private key to openssh!

Comment: noone should be using putty in 2022. windows provides proper ssh support now.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers given here do not explain the details for the most basic usage.

After you have setup a server (in this case a `linux` server) in the cloud, you connect to it using ssh from the terminal.

From your computer, add the private key `dyson-ubuntu-vm.pem` which is given to you by your cloud services provider such as Azure, AWS etc to your .ssh configuration on your local machine like this:

Copy the `.pem` file to the `/home/ssenyonjo/.ssh` folder, then open `/home/ssenyonjo/.ssh/config` file and add the following entry:

```
Host 20.85.213.44
  HostName 20.85.213.44
  User Dyson
  IdentityFile /home/ssenyonjo/.ssh/dyson-ubuntu-vm.pem
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now from your terminal, access the cloud linux server like so:

```
ssh Dyson@20.85.213.44
```

When that works, create a git project on the cloud server like so:

```
Dyson@dyson-ubuntu-vm:~/projects$ git init --bare s2
```

Now come back to your local machine and clone that empty repository like so:

```
ssenyonjo@ssenyonjo-pc:~/Projects/mastering-git$ git clone ssh://Dyson@20.85.213.44/home/Dyson/projects/s2
```

If you see an error that looks something like: `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`, It means you're accessing the wrong folder. Ensure you have outlined the right path from the root to the created repository.

If you dont want to setup a config file but want to access the ssh server that requires a key, you can use below command:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/Projects/aws/keys/aws_ubuntu.pem'  git clone ssh://ubuntu@15.207.99.158/home/ubuntu/projects/mastering-git/rand
```

You can export the command to continue using it for other tasks like `git push` and `git pull`

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/Projects/aws/keys/aws_ubuntu.pem'
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754018/10030693

Answer (score 4):

To have GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable work under Windows(CMD) instead of:

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i private_key_file"
```

Use:

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i private_key_file"
```

The quote has to be like

```
set "variable=value"
```

Some backgorund: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/10671021

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this method is, at least when running by bash.exe on Windows, that it will create a new process every time which will remain dormant.

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey; git clone git@github.com:user/project.git'
```

If you want want to use that for syncig repo on schedule then you need to add "&& ssh-agent -k" at the end.

Something like:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add C:/Users/user/.ssh/your_key; git -C "C:\Path\to\your\repo" pull && ssh-agent -k'
```

ssh-agent -k will kill the process when it's done.

Answer (score 4):

Also, as a simple "workaround", if you don't really need it that often:

Remove all ssh identities from the currently running ssh agent (not physically).

```
ssh-add -D
```

Re-add the one you need to work with to your currently running ssh-agent

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/MyProperProfile
```

Do the gits

Optionally - revert by adding other identities (or all of 'em).

Comment: NOTE: The command will delete all your keys!!! @Der Zinger Please Note this in your post with a Bold text!

Comment: I don't really get what this "warning" should be about sir.
This command (`ssh-add -D`) quote: `Removes all identities from the agent.`. It does not `delete` anything from anywhere. The actual keys are still physically there, exactly where they where before that command, and can be easily re-added with the next command I've listed. The only thing this command do - makes sure that `ssh-agent` (and everything that relies on it, like `git`) does not "know" about your keys.

Answer (score 3):

## This is an extension to  @VonC's answer. Please read it first.

Use case is I need to use both personal and work GitHub accounts using SSH. I want to use work SSH key as default as my projects will internally have other work  repos as dependency. So cloning them should work seamlessly.

Steps I followed are:

- Generate default SSH key and add it to work git account.
- Generate personal SSH key in a separate file and add it to personal git account.
- Add the following function code in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file and source it.

  ```
   gclone() { 
       # Clone the repo-url using personal ssh-key
       git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i path_to_personal_key" clone "$1" &&

       # Extract repo name from URL using "awk" and switch to that folder using "cd" 
       cd $(awk '{ sub(/.*\//, ""); sub(/\.git.*/, ""); print }' <<< "$1") &&

       # Set personal ssh-key as default for this repo 
       git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i path_to_personal_key";
   }
  ```
- Use `gclone` command to clone repos using personal SSH key and set the repo to use that key as default.
- Use normal `git clone` command to clone repos with default(work) SSH key.

Answer (score 3):

Clone in one command

```
git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -i /path/to/key/' clone git@github.com:your_repository.git /path/target/clone --branch git_branch_name
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting an SSH **permission denied Error** when running commands like *git push*, *pull*, or *fetch* even after you have copied your SSH public key to GitHub.

> NOTE 
> Use `--local` when you're in a local git repo, 
> but use `--global` when you want to apply to all repos

Use this:

```
git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /path-to-ssh-private-key'
```

E.g

```
git config --add --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/github-key'
```

You're done!

Optionally you can verify your change with this:

```
git config --local --get core.sshCommand
```

Comment: This worked for me. And the simplest

Answer (score 1):

I use `zsh` and different keys are loaded to my zsh shell's `ssh-agent` automatically for other purposes (i.e. access to remote servers) on my laptop. I modified @Nick's answer and I'm using it for one of my repos that needs to be refreshed often. (In this case it's my `dotfiles` which I want same and latest version across my all machines, wherever I'm working.)

```
bash -c 'eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add /home/myname/.dotfiles/gitread; ssh-add -L; cd /home/myname/.dotfiles && git pull; kill $SSH_AGENT_PID'
```

- Spawn an ssh-agent
- Add read-only key to agent
- Change directory to my git repo
- If `cd` to repo dir is successful, pull from remote repo
- Kill spawned ssh-agent. (I wouldn't want many of agents lingering around.)

Answer (score 1):

for the **gitlab** `RSAAuthentication yes`

```
Host gitlab.com
  RSAAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_private_key_name
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

[doc is here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths)

Comment: doesn't appear to be mentioned on the link you provided any more

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a ~/.ssh/config as below

```
Host <Your bitbucket server>
User <userid>
Hostname <Your bitbucket server as above>
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa<file> This is your private key file
```

permission as below

```
-rw------- $HOME/.ssh/config
```

Add your public key into your git  (cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pub [or simillar name])

and then git clone as below

```
git clone ssh://blahblah@blah.com/userid/test.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this requirement with following command option to git clone --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i /d/repos/ssh/prod-a/.ssh/id_ed25519"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've got **two accounts with different ssh keys**. I wanted to clone a repository, so how i did it:

*id_ed25519* - is the name of second key, usually default key is: *~/.ssh/id_rsa*

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

If you use a Github you can *check correct auth* with command below:

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

*Clone* or *Pull* code with command below:

(for the first time)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:username/path-somewhere.git
```

(for the next time)

```
$ git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GIT_SSH environment variable. But you will need to wrap ssh and options into a shell script.

See git manual: `man git` in your command shell.

Answer (score 0):

If SSH port number is not 22(default), add `Port xx` in `~/.ssh/config`

In my case (synology),

```
Host my_synology
    Hostname xxxx.synology.me
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_xxxx
    User myname
    Port xx
```

Then clone using Host title in config. ("my_synology". to avoid @chopstik 's "*")

```
git clone my_synology:path/to/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, you can:

- Keep your ssh keys organized
- Keep your git clone commands simple
- Handle any number of keys for any number of repositories.
- Reduce your ssh key maintenance.

I keep my keys in my `~/.ssh/keys` directory.

I prefer convention over configuration.

I think code is law; the simpler it is, the better.

**STEP 1 - Create Alias**

Add this alias to your shell:  `alias git-clone='GIT_SSH=ssh_wrapper git clone'`

**STEP 2 - Create Script**

Add this **ssh_wrapper** script to your PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filename: ssh_wrapper

if [ -z ${SSH_KEY} ]; then
    SSH_KEY='github.com/l3x'  # <= Default key
fi
SSH_KEY="~/.ssh/keys/${SSH_KEY}/id_rsa"
ssh -i "${SSH_KEY}" "$@"
```

**EXAMPLES**

Use github.com/l3x key:

```
KEY=github.com/l3x git-clone https://github.com/l3x/learn-fp-go
```

The following example also uses the **github.com/l3x** key (by default):

```
git-clone https://github.com/l3x/learn-fp-go
```

Use bitbucket.org/lsheehan key:

```
KEY=bitbucket.org/lsheehan git-clone git@bitbucket.org:dave_andersen/exchange.git
```

**NOTES**

Change the default SSH_KEY in the ssh_wrapper script to what you use most of the time. That way, you don't need to use the KEY variable most of the time.

You may think, "Hey! That's a lot going on with an alias, a script and some directory of keys," but for me it's convention.  Nearly all my workstations (and servers for that matter) are configured similarly.

My goal here is to simplify the commands that I execute regularly.

My conventions, e.g., Bash scripts, aliases, etc., create a consistent environment and helps me keep things simple.

KISS and names matter.

For more design tips check out *Chapter 4 SOLID Design in Go* from my book: [https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Functional-Programming-Lex-Sheehan-ebook/dp/B0725B8MYW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0725B8MYW)

Hope that helps. - Lex

Comment: it's much easier to just use includeif and a series of config files that set teh sshCommand

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things, just use `ssh-add` to add a temporary identity

```
alias gpullpersonal='ssh-add mykey;git pull;ssh-add -D'
alias gpullprofessional='ssh-add myotherkey;git pull;ssh-add -D'
```

Answer (score -6):

You can try [sshmulti](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sshmulti) npm package for maintaining multiple ssh key.

Comment: NPM package?! This should be a machine-related problem, useless yours is an application-related