# Howto pull latest revision of a git repository on system startup

Tags: linux, git, shell

I'm trying to update a git repository on system startup.

I called a Script from `/etc/rc.local` which is executed.
In that script I do the following steps:

1) Enter the folder where repo was cloned to
2) Do a git pull in that folder in two different ways
   1st way simple git pull > /home/user/result.txt (doesn't work)
   2nd way git --git-dir=/home/pi/gitrepo/.git pull origin master > /home/user/result.txt

What do I need to do to get this working?
Also tried to test if internet connection is already available with a simple wget which was successful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to be a problem with public key authentication.Note that commands during startup are executed as `root`, but you've likely registered a regular user's key at github.

Solution: register a [machine key at github](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) and use that key for the pull, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/171318)

Comment: Yes, but you also need to register the pub key of the machine user at github. Check the first link I provided