# Using git over ssh won't pick up private key

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh

My main development box uses Linux Mint.
When I am physically at the computer I can do remote operations like git fetch with no problem.

The user I log-in as is "jonbri".

```
> whoami
jonbri
```

In ~/.ssh (/home/jonbri/.ssh) is my private key (/home/jonbri/.ssh/jonbri) and public key (/home/jonbri/.ssh/jonbri.pub).

But when I am at another computer, for example another Linux Mint computer, and on the command-line I open a ssh remote shell to my main computer, when I try operations such as git fetch, it looks like the keys in ~/.ssh are not being picked up.

Here's what I see (with pwd being the root of the git repo):

```
> git fetch
Password:
```

Then, even no matter which password I enter it doesn't work.

To enable the ability to open a remote ssh shell I used apt-get to install open-ssh-server and open-ssh-client.

Any ideas why my keys aren't being picked up when inside a remote ssh shell.

Answer (score 2):

SSH is likely expecting the standard names of `id_dsa` for your private key and `id_dsa.pub` for your public key.

From the [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/):

> Check the directory listing to see if you already have a public SSH key. 
>       The default public key file names are:
>
> - id_dsa.pub
> - id_ecdsa.pub
> - id_ed25519.pub
> - id_rsa.pub

Comment: Is there a way to tell git/ssh to use a key with a custom name?

Comment: See this post for how to configure SSH keys - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/1427161