# Bare git repo on local machine cloned to server via key-based login

Tags: git, ssh

I have a webserver which only allows key-based ssh login. If I host the bare git repo on this machine, I can push and pull from my local machine with only [moderate pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby). But how can I push and pull from the server from a bare repo hosted on my local machine?

Note: I'm behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bare repository, trying to run `git push` will probably return something like:

```
fatal: The current branch foo has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin foo
```

You can use `git push --mirror` to push *all* references to your remote. Because this command is designed to replicate a repository you don't need to specify any information about remote tracking branches -- it will sync everything.  From the `git-pull` man page:

> `--mirror`
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
>      refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
>      refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote
>      repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote
>      end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
>      and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the
>      default if the configuration option remote..mirror is set.

Running `git pull` in a bare repository doesn't really make any sense (beacuse `git pull` is effectively `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, and there is no local branch into which you can merge upstream changes).  You can run `git remote update` or `git fetch` to bring in new objects from the remote repository.