# How to fix Cygwin using wrong .ssh directory no matter what I do?

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

On my Cygwin machine `$HOME` is `cygwdrive/c/Users/me` (i.e. not the sometimes default of `/home/me`) which I appreciate.

However, when I am using git, and trying to use ssh keys, it always checks in `/home/me/.ssh` for my keys.

To get around this, I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/3291506) however, putting a `config` file in `~/.ssh` doesn't work because I then have copy that same file to `/home/me/.ssh` because that is where git (when run from Cygwin) looks.

Is there some way I can avoid this?  As it stands right now I have to duplicate the file in each place or link them (which I want to avoid).  What I do not understand is why git insists on thinking my home folder is different than it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

As explained on Cygwin mailing list:
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-06/msg00404.html

> OpenSSH never honors $HOME.  It checks explicitely for your home dir
>   setting in the user DB.  See
>   https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html for various methods
>   setting your home dir.