# git clone with different username/account

Tags: git, clone

How can I `clone` a repository on `git` with an account that's different from what I was previously using?

For example, I might have been using one account for cloning one repo, and now I need to access another repo that only a different account has access to.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you clone via https you can do something like

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

This will prompt you for a password.

You can also directly provide a password by calling

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

But be aware that the password will be saved in .git/config and your bash history in that case which is not safe.
If you don't like to enter the password every time you should consider cloning via ssh.

Comment: I've got an ssh like this: git clone ssh://[somelongcode]@[a]-[b].rhcloud.com/~/git/[a].git/

I am using an ssh I got from openshift (a webhosting service I am using)

If I don't touch it I get: Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: In your example using ssh `[somelongcode]` would be the user name. Try to replace it with the correct user name. You can also try to do a `ssh [somelongcode]@[a]-[b].rhcloud.com` to see if ssh is working.

Comment: Then you might want to try [using another key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby) for authentication, I forgot how openshift works exactly, but this could be a solution.

Comment: This still isn't working from terminal. I can see it and (something like 'clone') using through the Github desktop.  But git clone isn't working even after entering a valid userame:password - I get "authentication failed." But the repositories do show correctly in desktop.

Comment: Your password is your personal access token if you have two factor auth

Comment: Github removed support for password authentication on August 13, 2021. If you want to clone using HTTPS see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73722165/5925582

Answer (score 27):

I tried above solution but it seems that support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

The solution is to use a personal access token which you can generate in `Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens`.

After that:

```
git clone https://username:personal-access-token@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: this should really be the main accepted answer now since password use has been removed from github

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple account with same version control system, you can setup your ssh config file to use different identity files as below:

For ex: You have created two identities in your .ssh folder (Windows: C:\Users\{yourUserName}\.ssh, Linux/MAC: ~/. ssh) with below names,

- **'personal'** (for personal bitbucket, github or any other account) and
- **'work'** (for your office bitbucket, github or any other account)

You can update your config file in .ssh folder like below,

```
# Global options
Host *
  # Always only use specified identities, do not fall back to
  # everything found in ssh-agent.
  IdentitiesOnly yes

# Repeat following for each context
## When in "personal" context directory, use "personal" ssh key for bitbucket.org or github.com
Host personal
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal

## When in "work" context directory, use "work" ssh key for bitbucket.org or github.com
### Of course, other hosts that require this context
### can be added as well, just using the host name
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

And once you clone any project from **personal** version control system (bitbucket or github or anything else),

### For Personal:

make sure to use 'personal' as host name.

✓

```
git clone git@personal:mypersonalworkspace/myproject.git
```

instead of

✕

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:mypersonalworkspace/myproject.git
```

### For Work:

For work project you can continue using

✓

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myofficeworkspace/myproject.git
```

Comment: This works _great_! Thank you! For github, it's just as useful; just set host to github.com.

Answer (score 1):

Github removed support for password authentication on August 13, 2021. If you want to clone using HTTPS follow instructions bellow.

When you git clone, git fetch, git pull, or git push to a remote repository using HTTPS URLs on the command line, Git will ask for your GitHub username and password. When Git prompts you for your password, enter your personal access token (PAT). Password-based authentication for Git has been removed in favor of more secure authentication methods. For more information, see "[Creating a personal access token.](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)"
Alternatively, you can use a credential helper like [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/README.md).

Reference: Github page [Cloning with HTTPS](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls)

Answer (score -1):

If this account's ssh-key has been added to your device, you can try this after ssh-add.

```
git clone git@<account_username>:<repo_username>/repository.git
```

Hope this could help.