# Git clone with different accounts according to the folder

Tags: git

I configured 2 Git accounts for my user in my laptop, one for work-related stuff, another for personal stuff.

The system configuration file in `/etc/gitconfig` is empty.

The global configuration file in `~/.gitconfig` contains the following setup:

```
# Users config
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Coding/Personal/**"]
        path = ~/Coding/Personal/.gitconfig
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Coding/Work/**"]
        path = ~/Coding/Work/.gitconfig
```

The two `.gitconfig` files referred to within the global config file both contain the same setup:

```
[credential]
    username = <work_or_personal_username>
[user]
    name = <work_or_personal_name>
    email = <work_or_personal_email>
```

However, when I'm trying to clone a repo within any of the 2 paths `~/Coding/*`, `git` always resolves to the work-user. In fact, I can clone every public repo, but I can only clone work-related repo, not my own private repo. If I clone a work-related private repo within `~/Coding/Personal`, every `git` operation I run inside of the repo's local directory will be done with the personal account.

How should I setup `git` to be able to clone with different accounts according to the folder I'm in?

NB: I already checked [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644366/git-clone-with-different-username-account), but none of them turned out useful for my case.

Comment: `includeIf` works only in **repositories** under `~/Coding/Work/`; see [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdircode)" "*If the location of the .git directory matches the pattern…*"; i.e, `includeIf` needs `.git/` to exist. When you're cloning a new repo there is no repository yet so `includeIf` doesn't work. For cloning you need to find out a different way to authorize. When cloning finishes and you `cd` into the cloned repo then `includeIf` will start taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conditional config only work with repository match these conditions. But when you clone, it still does not exists.

For problem using 2 account for 2 git server (different domain), it depends on your credential for each remote. The simplest way I usually use is ssh key.
You can use only 1 key for 2 accounts then when you clone it will auto match by domain.

In case you use 2 accounts in the same domain, you can use different protocol, http for the first, ssh for the other.
Or if you want more than 2, GIT_SSH_COMMAND is the best solution. Follow this link (last section): https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/managing-multiple-accounts

Comment: I was able to write a git-wrapper to include the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` env-var according to the folder I'm running the command in, thanks!