# Fabric command not working with specific ssh key

Tags: python, git, ssh, fabric

I'm working with fabric3 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3) ,  a python 3 port of fabric.

I have the following function wchich I'm running locally in win7 using git-bash:

```
@roles('production')
def dir():
    env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/deploy'
    local("git push mysite master")
    run('pwd')
    run('ls')
    code_dir = '/home/deploy/mysite'
    with cd(code_dir):
        run('pwd')
        run('git reset --hard master')
        run('ls -la')
```

output:

```
$ fab dir
[deploy@198.x.x.x] Executing task 'dir'
[localhost] local: git push mysite master
deploy@198.x.x.x's password:
```

When I run the function, I get asked for the password. It seems to be ignoring the key. How can I get the function to use the prescribed key?

Comment: Is the password asked by `git push`?

Comment: yes it appears so.

Comment: `git push` executed from under `fabric` connects to the remote host using a separate connection that is not managed by `fabric`.

Comment: Because git uses the ssh-agent, you will need to run something like this. [Specify private SSH-key to use when executing shell command with or without Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I added git as a user to my .ssh/config file and it now appears to work.

```
Host deploy
HostName 198.x.x.x
User deploy
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host 198.x.x.x
HostName 198.x.x.x
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy
```