# bitbucket, ssh key can't have name other than id_rsa

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

if my key is named id_rsa.pub and I put it into bitbucket ssh setting. It is working out of box. When I ssk-keygen name like id_rsa_else.pub, then insert to ssh key setting. It is saying

```
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Update 1**

the following gives me the error above:

```
Host andatech_bitbucket_my_username
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User andatech_my_username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/andatech_my_username_bitbucket
```

Comment: git or mercurial?

Comment: I am using git at the moment.

Comment: Some possible solutions are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby

Comment: username for bitbucket should be "git" and not andatech_....

Comment: Also: did you add the andatech_my_username_bitbucket key to bitbucket. Because in the beginning of your question you're talking about id_rsa_else as the name of the key.

Comment: I change user to git. andatech_my_username_bitbucket is inside ssh key setting in my uesr profilke in bitbucket. Same error repository access denied.

Comment: Bitbucket does permit the username instead of "git" or "hg" when the key is associated with a specific account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Host bitbucket.org 
  HostName bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/andatech_xxx_bitbucket
```

Based on this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html

Comment: Looks good so far. Does it work? If not, what happens when you run `ssh -Tvv git@bitbucket.org`?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your ssh config file. 
It's usually the file: `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_else
```

`id_rsa_else` is the name of your key. This tells ssh which private key to use when talking to bitbucket.org.

Comment: "the following not working:" is kind of vague... Se my comments above

Answer (score 0):

Are the remotes on your repos listed as "andatech_bitbucket_my_username" or as "bitbucket.org"? (You can run `git remote get-url origin` to see the URL for the remote named "origin".) If the first part of the URL isn't "andatech_bitbucket_my_username", then SSH won't refer to that stanza in your config, and as a result it won't use the key you want.

If that's the problem, then you can fix it in one of two ways: either update repos to use "andatech_bitbucket_my_username" instead of "git@bitbucket.org" or whatever you have listed there (`git remote set-url origin andatech_bitbucket_my_username`), or update your ~/.ssh/config to have `Host bitbucket.org` in place of `Host andatech_bitbucket_my_username`.