# Ansible task - clone private git without SSH forwarding

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create an Ansible playbook which would be run from our dev team computers and from CI/CD servers.

One of the tasks in the playbook is to get the source code of our project from a private git repository. Because the playbook has to run from CI/CD servers we can not use SSH forwarding.

What i came up with is to copy necessary SSH private key to remote host machine and then using the key clone the code from the private git repository.

However when trying this, the cloning task hangs. When trying to launch the command manually it asks for a passphrase for the SSH private key. SSH key uses no passphrase (blank).

**Could anyone share their solution of this (probably very common) problem?**

In case anyone needs, this is my current playbook:

```
- name: Create SSH directory
  file: path=/root/.ssh state=directory

- name: Copy SHH key for Git access
  copy:
    content: "{{ git_ssh_key }}"
    dest: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0600

# Also tried this, but it also hangs
#- name: Start SSH agent and add SSH key
#  shell: eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add

- name: Get new source from GIT
  git: 
    key_file: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    repo: "git@gitlab.com:user/repo.git"
    dest: "{{ staging_dir }}"
    depth: 1
    accept_hostkey: yes
    clone: yes
```

I am using `ansible 2.3.1.0, python version = 2.7.12`

Comment: "*When trying to launch the command manually it asks for a passphrase for the SSH private key.*" -- how is that a programming problem?

Comment: i need a way to write a task to enter the passphrase (programming problem) or a different approach where i would not need to enter it at all (operations problem).

Comment: Use a key without a passphrase.

Comment: @techraf i did, the process still hangs. how can i debug this?

Comment: It hangs, because from your own words, even if you call "the command" manually it asks for a passphrase. Describe how you generated the key and what commands you execute on SuperUser. It is off-topic for StackOverflow .

Comment: I assume the user running the playbook is root? When running `ssh-keygen -yf ` is a passphrase required? Does the second line of `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` contain the word `ENCRYPTED`?

Comment: @damien yes, i run the playbook as rot user. ```ssh-keygen -yf``` asks for password. No, ENCRYPTED is not there.

Comment: Is the connection successful after you enter the blank passphrase? Have you tried removing the (empty) passphrase with `ssh-keygen -p` or considering generating a new key?

Comment: i am willing to create a new key, what options shouldi use in order to create a passwordless ssh key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are steps to make it work (tested with Ansible 2.3.1 and Python 2.7.10 on MacOS, Ubuntu LTS):

1. Generate new SSH key pair without passphrase `ssh-keygen -f my_ssh_key -N ''`.
2. Add `my_ssh_key.pub` to your repository server user profile

   - GitLab - https://gitlab.com/profile/keys
   - Github - https://github.com/settings/keys
3. Test with the following playbook:

_

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    git_ssh_public_key: "Your public ssh key"
    git_ssh_key: |
              -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
              .... actual key here ....
              -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  tasks:
  - name: Copy SSH public key file
    copy: 
      content: "{{ git_ssh_public_key }}"
      dest: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      mode: 0644

  - name: Copy SSH private key file
    copy: 
      content: "{{ git_ssh_key }}"
      #src: id_rsa
      dest: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
      mode: 0600

  - name: Get new source from GIT
    git: 
      repo: "git@gitlab.com:user/repo.git"
      dest: "/var/www/"
      depth: 1
      accept_hostkey: yes
      clone: yes
```

**IMPORTANT SECURITY NOTICES**

*If you want to use this example in real world, please do not save your private key in plaintext - use [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_vault.html).*

*You should also **NOT** use root as your ansible user. It would be more secure to create new user without sudo permissions.*

Comment: this still does not work for me.. when trying to ```git fetch``` it still asks for passphrase ```Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':```. Maybe there is some SSH configuration parameter which would bypass passphrase asking when it is blank?

Comment: Why `git fetch`? Check with ansible `git` module. And ensure that supplied key file is valid for your repo server.

Comment: In ansible script i am using default command which you gave. But it hangs doing nothing. That is why i manually connected to the target machine and tested git command which would connect to my private repo. Even if the key is generated witout passphrase, it still asks to enter it (just hit enter).

Comment: Everything worked when i also copied the public key. Edited your answer and accepted it. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that for the automated task, git is not using a ssh key. I've read (by looking around for a couple of minutes) that with git 2.10, you can provide ssh stuff to pass when calling git.... so I guess you could try something like:

```
git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -i /path/to/private/key' fetch origin
```

Or whatever other command you would like to use. You could also fix it in configuration:

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i /path/to/private/key'
```

Anyway, hope that helps a little bit

[Specify private SSH-key to use when executing shell command with or without Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-with-or-without-ruby)

Comment: i am using git v.1.7.1, so this does not work for me.