# Unable to push project from local to git repository set up in AWS : Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, laravel, amazon-web-services, public-key

I am new to AWS and followed a tutorial to set up git in aws and the push my local files into it. I have a Key with me with .pem extension which got generated while I was creating the instance. 
I have added the remote repository like this:
`git remote add production ssh://root@35.154.37.131/var/repo/site.git`

after this when I tried to push into the repository I got:

```
 $ git push production master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I googled but not able to follow the solutions. 
However, I could ssh to my instance using:

```
ssh -i wexpert_instance_2.pem ubuntu@ec2-35-154-37-131.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

please help.

Comment: You may find https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use useful.

Comment: Or try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/specify-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command

Comment: And you may want to ensure the username matches (`root` in your original remote command vs `ubuntu` in your ssh command).

Comment: @msbit is right, you're probably using the wrong user as well as not using the public DNS. Try changing the remote to use: `ssh://ubuntu@ec2-35-154-37-131.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/var/repos/site.git`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I tried doing `git remote add production ssh://ubuntu@ec2-35-154-37-131.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/var/repos/site.git`
But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing git remote add production ssh://ubuntu@ec2-35-154-37-131.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/var/repos/site.git

That is expected, because SSH will look for your key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` by default.

Since you don't have a default key, you need to define a ~/.ssh/config file (chmod 644), with:

```
Host myaws
Hostname ec2-35-154-37-131.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile /full/path/to/wexpert_instance_2.pem
```

Then:

```
git remote set-url production myaws:/var/repo/site.git
```