# SSH key per project in Gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, virtual-machine

i have a problem that i don't know how to handle.

I have 2 Repos in Gitlab , RepoA and RepoB. In my gitlab user i have 3 ssh keys, one from my laptop and 2 from the 2 VM (VMA and VMB) that work with the 2 repos. In this way i can pull and push easy from the VMs and from my laptop.

On RepoA i have a colaborator that also works. He has RepoA shared to his Gitlab account and he has access to VMA to push and pull code. He sould never have access to RepoB, so from here comes my problem. If he can guess the RepoB url , he can pull and see it on the VMA where he has access already just becouse Gitlab does not have a granular way o adding ssh keys per project. I probably am missing something very logical here but i just can't see what.

How can i give access to to my colaborator on VMA to only see RepoA.

A hack-ish way of doing this is to generate a 3rd user in gitlab that handles just VMA an the ssh key from VMA  will be introduced in this user account on Gitlab. But i bet there's got to be a better, cleaner way.

Comment: consider creating a new user account on the VM for the collaborator, and let him have his own key, and give him access only to repoA on gitlab

Comment: GitLab has the feature of project-specific SSH keys: They are called "Deployment keys" and you can use them for read-only or read/write access.

Comment: "Deployment keys"  are the solution. I tried it and it works. Thanks @Robert .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GitLab has the feature of project-specific SSH keys:

They are called **[Deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/index.html)**. You can use them to provide read-only or read/write access for one or multiple repositories.

> Use deploy keys to access repositories that are hosted in GitLab.
> Deploy keys can’t be used for Git operations if external authorization is enabled.

Comment: Ok, but how would GitLab know which key to use for which repository? For example, if I had 3 repositories, each with a separate deploy key, and I would like to clone only two of them, or push to one specific repository? Is it possible to configure it somewhere, e.g., in ~/.ssh/config, or in a specific .git for a given repository which key should be used when communicating with a remote server?

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald I would add the key to be used to the ssh agent before performing the git command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565746/150978

Answer (score 1):

There is also [this feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#use-different-keys-for-different-repositories):

### Use different keys for different repositories

You can use a different key for each repository.

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/private-key-filename-for-this-repository -F /dev/null"
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the goal of allowing certain SSH keys to access specific repos on GitLab.