# Issues using bitbucket git repository source for downloading a module over SSH

Tags: git, bitbucket, terraform

When calling a module over from a local source everything went alright, however I decided to refactor the Terraform code to use a git repository for modules.

I created a new repository in our BitBucket account with the name terraform-modules, and refactored the source attribute of the modules to have the following structure:

```
source     = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket.org:carepaydev/terraform-modules.git//modules/iam/iam_roles/assumable_role"
```

When calling `terraform init` I get the following error:

```
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<username>/terraform-modules.git': /usr/local/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/caf541f5e5ccbb1d204bce3b94091014'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:<username>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Cloning the repository using git clone does work. I tried setting the `TF_LOG` env var to `TRACE` to see if that would give me more insight, but that did not help.

Any clue why this fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the colon between `ssh://git@bitbucket.org` and `username/repo` to a slash:

`ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/repo`

In that format, the colon indicates an alternate port - useful if you want to do `ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/username/repo`, and similar to how you'd specify an alternate port for other protocols like HTTP.

Comment: Is it possible to make it generic so that all team members could use it? Like using some env variables?

Comment: Both of these forms are already generic. The `username` listed here is the *owner* of the repo, which could be a team or individual; changing the `username` will send requests to a different repo.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you need to reference a specific tag in your repo.
Please note that the module name can be a path to your module or submodules directory e.g module/submodule

```
source = "git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git//modulename?ref=tagvalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar error with [hashicorp/terraform issue 12696](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12696), when trying to access a private repository.

At least, try and set [`git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -Tvv"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474137/6309), in order to see what private key is actually used by Terraform durong the `git clone` process.