# GitLab SSH Keys not working in project directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created an SSH key and when I run `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` in GitBash as admin I get `Welcome to GitLab, @myname` so that's working, but the moment I run the same within a directory where all my files that i'm trying to push to an empty git project I get `git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).`

I've read the docs but cant figure out what I'm doing wrong why does it work in the root of the PC and not in the folder where I actually have the file I need to send to git?

Working

```
My.Name@My-Mac MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, @joshwordshop!
```

Not working

```
My.Name@My-Mac MINGW64 /c/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah(master)
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

NOTE: Running windows on a Mac so if you post any commands can you do so in their windows form, thank you in advanced

Comment: You need to go through a couple of checks... e.g. which credentials are set (see in `git config --local -l`). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4565700/4183044) might have useful information on your ssh-key usage

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your publickey to your GitLab profile? You can find those settings under: `Profile -> SSH Keys`

You can find more instructions inside GitLab's documentation [here](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#locating-an-existing-ssh-key-pair)