# Clone repository in post-process function in Yocto

Tags: git, yocto, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565746/881712) answer, I'm trying to clone a repository inside the a post-process function in my Yocto process:

```
my_postprocess_function() {
  ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/mark/.ssh/key; git clone git@gitlab.com:<myrepo> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/opt/;'
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "my_postprocess_function; "
```

It says:

> ssh-agent: not found

Of course `ssh-agent` is installed in my machine, but it's not found when the function is executed.

Why?

Comment: What are you trying to achive because the question seems strange. Maybe I can provide an alternative or solve it then

Comment: The goal is to have in the final image a clone of a git repository. In this way I can just login on the target and issue "git pull" to update the files.

Comment: @FlorianBerndl, any alternative idea?

Comment: Well, it seems a bit complex for such a simple task. I've ended up mounting the image as devloop and then do whatever I need using a bash script. Anyway, I appreciate a lot your willingness.