# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) while Public key already added to github

Tags: git, github

I have added the public key to my Github as the contents of ssh-keygen generated testkey.pub , while corresponding testkey is in my local machine already. When i'm trying to push after commiting, it gives me below error.

```
 C:\CRMNext\Git\speech_to_text_auto_2>dir testkey.pub
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8EE7-4A30

 Directory of C:\CRMNext\Git\speech_to_text_auto_2

31-05-2020  17:51               753 testkey.pub
               1 File(s)            753 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  573,783,420,928 bytes free

C:\CRM\Git\speech_to_text_auto_2>git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Sarrae1406/speech_to_text_auto_2.git (push)

C:\CRM\Git\speech_to_text_auto_2>git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Unable to understand why I am still getting issues with public key access.

Output for ssh -Tv git@github.com is as below:

```
C:\CRM\Git\speech_to_text_auto_2>ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.210.38] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f6e22739
debug1: no match: babeld-f6e22739
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:oO3mEoN/peXiKM2lmj07Sa6JY+IASJ88bsIM2tgOawA C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Have you told your local git to use your `testkey`?

Comment: @fredrik How do i do that

Comment: There are several different options in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git

Comment: Please show the text output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com`

Comment: @phd Have added the output needed, in the question. Pls see.

Comment: ssh cannot find the private key in the directory `C:\\Users\\KASTURI/.ssh/`