# Git always prompts "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?"

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I have ssh setup in `~/.config/ssh` instead of the default `~/.ssh`.

Every time I do a `git pull` or `git push`, I get the below message:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

After entering *yes*, the next step of adding the host to the `known_hosts` fails, but the operation (`git pull` and `git push`) completes successfully.

There is no `~/.ssh` (and thereby no `~/.ssh/known_hosts`) after the operation completes.

The location of my known hosts file is: `~/.config/ssh/known_hosts`.

I have already done:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.config/ssh/known_hosts -T git@github.com
```

**and**

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add -K ~/.config/ssh/id_rsa
```

and also added the SSH keys to my github profile using `pbcopy < ~/.config/ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Contents of `~/.config/ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.config/ssh/id_rsa
```

Contents of `~/.config/ssh/known_hosts`:

```
github.com,192.30.255.112 ssh-rsa ...
...
...==
192.30.255.113 ssh-rsa ...
...
...==
```

File permissions of `~/.config/ssh`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 username  staff   192 Aug 29 19:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 username  staff   224 Aug 29 16:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff    83 Aug 29 19:01 config
-rw-------  1 username  staff  3434 Aug 29 19:00 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff   747 Aug 29 19:00 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff   803 Aug 29 19:31 known_hosts
```

**EDIT**:

Doing `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$HOME/.config/ssh/known_hosts git@github.com` gives:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
```

How do I avoid entering 'yes' at every `git pull` and `git push` ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the hosts file path, plus your shell probably isn't expanding the tilde since it's in the middle of a string.  Does the host key show up in your known_hosts file after accepting it?

Comment: @StephenNewell no it does not. After entering *yes*, the pull/push operation continues (see first code block). There is no `~/.ssh` directory (and no `known_hosts` file in it).

Comment: Sorry, missed that in your question.  Check permissions on the file.

Comment: I've added file permissions of the directory. Please have a look.

Comment: As @StephenNewell said, `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.config/ssh/known_hosts` is leaving the tilde *un-expanded*. Your ssh probably does not handle that (the one on my Mac does not for instance). Use `$HOME` instead of `~` so that it will be expanded.

Comment: @torek I'm getting a message about usage. Added it to the question.

Comment: That's because `ssh -o ...` is missing the required `destination` argument. It's `ssh github.com` for instance, or `ssh -o ... github.com`. In general you should not need to use the `-o` option at all, unless you want to override the built in default known hosts file. I use the standard location and omit the `-o`, but I assumed above that you had some reason to use a nonstandard location.

Comment: I just did `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$HOME/.config/ssh/known_hosts github.com`, but I'm getting a `Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions on [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) GitHub page, I executed the command `ssh -vT git@github.com`.

It gave the below output:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-c2ee9279
debug1: no match: babeld-c2ee9279
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:...
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/saurabh/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: saurab.mish@gmail.com RSA SHA256:...
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: saurab.mish@gmail.com RSA SHA256:...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/saurabh/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And the "-1" at the end of the "identity file" lines means SSH couldn't find a file to use.

I modified  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41612988/13055097) so that the private key is configured globally, to:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -i $HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=$HOME/.config/ssh/known_hosts -F /dev/null"
```

Answer (score 5):

Every time I was getting warning as-
*Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?*
**Fix:**

1. Open file-
   `nano ~/.ssh/config`
2. Following line should present-

As-

```
Host github.com
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

That worked for me.