# How to push to .git repository with an appropriate .ssh key?

Tags: macos, github, ssh, rsa

I have two ssh keys on my laptop: work.pub for work (and it is attached to my GitHub work account) and personal.pub (for personal usage and personal GitHub account). Also I am using macOS 11.0.1.

I have following .ssh/config:

```
Host *
   UseKeychain yes
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

I have added both ssh keys to Keychain with:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/work
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/personal
```

Still, when I tried to push to `personal` repo on GH I get error than `my_work_github_username` does not allowed to push (here I expected that my personal ssh key would take precedence)

After it failed I deleted all identities from Keychain and tried to push one more time:
`ssh-add -D`
It pushed to personal .git, but with `work` identity (git commit showed my `work` avatar and nickname, but I was expecting it to show my `personal` pic and nickname)

What am doing wrong? How to be able to use multiple keys on one system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with git 2.10, you can set a new configuration variable `core.sshCommand`. This specifies what value for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to use **per repository.**

See
[How to specify the private SSH-key to use when executing shell command on Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git/38474137#38474137)

Comment: Looks good! 
What about server ssh auth? How should I manage ssh keys in this situation?

Comment: For ssh, use the `-i` option option to specify the key

Comment: Thanks, and the last question!
May I somehow specify "repositories pattern", for which I want to apply certain ssh? e.g. if git remote has git@github.com:workrep -> apply work.pub?