# How to specify which ssh key to login to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have 2 GitHub accounts and an ssh key for each of them. Unfortunately ssh-agent always uses the first key unless I use my 3rd solution but then I can't specify the username for GitHub.

```
Here is my .bashrc which starts up ssh agent and adds those keys
/usr/bin/keychain --nogui $HOME/.ssh/account1 &> /dev/null;
/usr/bin/keychain --nogui $HOME/.ssh/account2 &> /dev/null;
source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh &> /dev/null;
```

Here are the multiple things I've tried for my ~/.ssh/config

1. I based it off this
   https://superuser.com/a/1525769

```
Host account1.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account1.pub

Host account2.git
  User git
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account2.pub
```

2. https://superuser.com/questions/357602/use-a-specified-key-from-ssh-agent

```
Host github.com-account1
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account1

Host github.com-account2
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account2
```

3. Only this one works but this solution isn't acceptable since my host is just github.com

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-manage-multiple-ssh-keys/

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account1
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Here is the error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also I tried this which works

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

These other ssh calls don't work

```
ssh -T git@github-account1
ssh -T git@github-account1.com
ssh -T git@xuhu55.github
```

I suspect that I'm not using the correct host but I honestly don't know why it would be incorrect.

Here's my GitHub account
https://github.com/xuhu55

so you can substitute xuhu55 where account1 appears.

Comment: do you mean the parameter after `-T` is account name, not target host?

Comment: @LeiYang I thought you would have account name and target host after -T? For example ssh -T git@github.com has git as the account name and github.com as target host. Apologies if I don't understand

Comment: @Raptor Unfortunately I tried that but none of those are working. For some reason I can't seem to add xuhu55 into my Host correctly even when I tried all their suggestions.

Comment: @developer so you know the string after `@` is the **host**, not the accout name, why do you expect `github-account1.com` or `xuhu55.github` to work, is there such host?

Comment: ok makes sense.

Comment: @Raptor I looked more thoroughly and one of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

1. Add email to git config locally
2. Invite email to become a collaborator of the git repo
3. Create ssh-key with email
4. Add SSH-Key from .pub to GitHub account
5. Test
6. Connect

**Boring stuff**:

Use `ssh-add` to select from your saved ssh-keys. I believe they are stored in `.ssh` if you're using Linux and in `User/` if you're on Windows. Example:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/myWorkGitHub
// enter password
```

Check if you are using the same **email** you used when generating the ssh by:

```
git config --list
```

if not, set the right configuration for your git.

**Note**: You should have added the contents of `myWorkGitHub.pub` to your GitHub account in order for the above code to work.

Ensure ssh is enabled:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
// will return a pid if successful
```

Test connection:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
//successful message from GitHub
```

If your repo is private, you should invite this `email` to become a collaborator of the repo.

All good?
Now you can connect to the repo remotely.

```
git push -u origin main
git@github.com:{YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME}/{YOUR_REPO_NAME}.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This specific ended up solving it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067132/16428455

So I ended up needing to do this

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account2

Host xuhu55
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/xuhu55
```

This is the thing that solved it for me.

```
git remote set-url origin git@xuhu55:xuhu55/Project3.git
```

Apparently my old ssh url origin had to be changed. I had to change github.com to xuhu55 to get it to work for me. This is very easy to overlook if you've already cloned the project with ssh.

```
git@github.com:xuhu55/Project3.git
```