# How to specify the private SSH-key to use when executing git pull?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I need to do a git pull specifying the private key, like:

```
git pull git@github.com:User/Repository.git -key "~/git_key"
```

I know that I can set the key on "~/.ssh/authorized_keys", but I don't want to set the key global, only to specify the key on the git command.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+specify+SSH+key

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754018/7976758: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/git_key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' git pull git@github.com:User/Repository.git`