# How to specify both a Bitbucket repository key and a user key such that the repository key is read-only and the user key provides push capability?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Bitbucket provides for setting up a key **on a repository** for **read-only** access.  Without debating the merits of the following methodology, I want to use this feature in order to `git pull` to deploy changes to websites (as user `root`), but I also want to provide for a non-`root` user to very occasionally be able to `push` to the repo from the web server using their own key.  I've assigned `root`'s default `id_rsa.pub` key as the Bitbucket repository key, and the `pull` (read-only) functionality is working when signed in as `root`.  However, I get an error when trying to `push` from a specific user.  The error is:

```
Load key "/home/user1/.ssh/bitbucket": Permission denied
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I am issuing the `git push` as `user1`, so I don't understand why it's giving a `Permission denied` error when trying to load the key.  Why can't `user1` load and use his own key?  The private part of both keys mentioned below has permissions set to 600, and the public part has permissions set to 644.

The setup:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Two users:  *root* and *user1*
- *root*'s `id_rsa.pub` key added to the Bitbucket repository's **Access Keys**
- *user1*'s key for accessing Bitbucket (named `bitbucket.pub`) added to the user's **SSH Keys** in BitBucket

A `config` file in `/root/.ssh/` with the following:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

A `config` file in `/home/user1/.ssh/` with the following:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git_user1
    IdentityFile /home/user1/.ssh/bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

`git remote -v` shows:

- `origin  git@bitbucket.org:our_bitbucket_organization/website-name.git (fetch)`
- `origin  git@bitbucket.org:our_bitbucket_organization/website-name.git (push)`

`user1` can `push` to the repo fine from their development server - the user is a user in the organization and so is a user on the repo.  I have also tried commenting out the `User` line in `user1`'s config file but get the same error.

I've also studied [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git) (and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25924462/5548239)) but can't find anything in there that quite addresses this error.  I want to have two separate `config` files, not a single `config` file.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Load key "/home/user1/.ssh/bitbucket": Permission denied

The error means the file is not readable by `user1`. To fix:

```
chown -R user1 /home/user1/.ssh
chmod -R u=rwX,go= /home/user1/.ssh
```

PS. This is more generic than just a fix for one file. Just in case.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!  A simple permissions error.  Thanks very much!