# Using Multiple SSH Keys to access Git

Tags: git, ssh

I have a setup with multiple ssh keys for multiple sources/users with different keys. To set up such environment I have followed various guides such as: [Multiple GitHub accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer) to do the set up.

To recap what happens: basically I have multiple ssh keys on my computer, for example I have my personal github, my personal bitbucket, work bitbucket. Each one of those set up with a made-up `Host` so that I can clone those using automatically different keys, as outlined in the above mentioned article.

For each remote the configured key works as it should when I am in a new shell, for example I can do git clone/push/pull with no problem with any of those.
However, if within the same shell I cd into a repo that needs a different key and I try any git command this one fails with the error:

```
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However if I run `ssh -t git@bit_personal` (made up host) or `ssh -t git@hvhr` (another made up host) or `ssh -t git@github.com`  it will work fine within the same shell.

To make the git push/pull etc command work a workaround I found is to run `ssh-add -D` before running it.

This is what my ssh config file looks like:

```
Host github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github

Host bit_personal
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket_personal

Host hvhr
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket_hvhr

Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_general
```

Running a `git remote -v` in the `bit_personal` repo I get:

```
origin  git@bit_personal:my_username/dot-files-dump.git (fetch)
origin  git@bit_personal:my_username/dot-files-dump.git (push)
```

and `git remote -v` in the company remote:

```
origin  git@hvhr:my_username/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@hvhr:my_username/repo.git (push)
```

[Successful request response from a matching bit_personal git remote debugged with GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git pull](https://pastebin.com/ugU5Dsyx) and [here](https://pastebin.com/wTqRSgpz) an unsuccessful request from the same repo. (Note: to reproduce in the same terminal I did a `git pull` of a repo matching `hvhr`. The main difference that I can see between the two requests is that the order of the `Will attempt key` is incorrect when it fails. When the request is successful I get this in the debug lines:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mimo/.ssh/id_bitbucket_personal ED25519 SHA256: explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mimo/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256: explicit
```

While when unsuccessful it uses the key matching the `Host *` key (which was successful at a previous pull in the same terminal):

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mimo/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:Qj6a9wU+leduocucbcjohcjakokghwpidtpllwbu explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mimo/.ssh/id_bitbucket_personal ED25519 SHA256:89otR+uzlbkcjkjxyifswgnwbdrlefssnwanbe explicit
```

git version 2.38.0

I'm using Mac OS 12.6, with ARM CPU, I tried this on different shells: zsh, sh, bash, all showing the same behavior.

Comment: `host` in `ssh -Tv git@host` must be one from `Host` directive, not `HostName`. The same for `git remote`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I typed in my queston `git@host` instead of `git@hostname`.

Comment: `git remote -v` ? `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push` ?

Comment: I added more details to the question with the `git remote -v` and the output of `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push`. Seems that the main difference between a successful and unsuccessful operation is that in the latter the attempted first key is going to be the last one used which was successful, but incorrect for the current repo.

Comment: Try [`IdentitiesOnly yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/7976758) … https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+IdentitiesOnly

Comment: Amazing, it was exactly what I needed to do for it to work :)