# How to differentiate two separate SSH Key pairs for Github and Gitlab

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab, key, ssh-keys

I created a Keypair for Github, and now I'm trying to create another Keypair for Gitlab following this guide https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html.

But how will I be able to differentiate both and know which Keypair belongs to which? Will putting different comments help me?

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "<comment>"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the private SSH-key to use when executing shell command on Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference them in a `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host ghUser1
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Host ghUser2
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

Replace User1 by your actual GitHub Username for instance.

You can then test the associated GitHub identity with:

```
ssh -T ghUser1
ssh -T ghUser2
```

And clone a repository with `git clone ghUser1:User1/aRepository`