# Permission denied (publickey). Bitbucket git pull doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, rsa, ssh-keys

I have been trying to debug this problem I am facing since 2 days now. I noticed this problem when I was trying to pull something from bitbucket. It says

```
git@code.pruconnect.net: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried every solution form deleting old ssh keys and adding new ones to adding the existing keys to the ssh-agent. Also, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` command again throws `git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)` as the error and `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org` throws the following as the error:

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_44eee6a33e b7cd6ff70e1a
debug1: compat_banner: no match: conker_44eee6a33e b7cd6ff70e1a
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 2 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:nux65XHIgoNnct40pwEJWQ+kLrA2W2r0oqm9PHGvH1Q explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: amijeet.thakur@wedopulse.co.in RSA SHA256:1YofMNkb/JQpdGd8OZlyyjaX9RQR0h9c6ZWzZMDlWes agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/amijeetthakur/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:nux65XHIgoNnct40pwEJWQ+kLrA2W2r0oqm9PHGvH1Q explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: amijeet.thakur@wedopulse.co.in RSA SHA256:1YofMNkb/JQpdGd8OZlyyjaX9RQR0h9c6ZWzZMDlWes agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Note: I observed this error to come after updating my Mac to MacOs Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already added SSH key then try setting URL

get the SSH URL from bit-bucket then,

```
git remote set-url origin "SSHURL"
```

paste URL without quotes.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering. Tried this solution, but sadly the problem persists. Could you please suggest something else that might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the *~/.ssh* folder and the keys have the correct permissions set.

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Remember that you can specify which key to use, in case you got more than one key-pair. Specify the private key, not the public key:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host
```

When dealing with several key-pairs, the ssh client needs to know which key to use. Add the following lines in *~/.ssh/config*:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_private_key
```

Comment: Hi @psq, thank you so much for answering. I tried the first solution you suggested, but the problem persists. Could you please tell me what should I add as the host in the second solution, if I am using bitbucket?

Comment: @AmijeetThakur I have edited my answer to add more info. If you only have keys with the default names, I doubt it'll help. In that case, I would need more info about your environment. Is it ok to share the output of `git remote -v` (in your repo), `ls -al ~ | grep '\.ssh'` and `ls -al ~/.ssh`. That will allow us to see the permissions of files, and whether you're hitting the SSH or HTTPS url of your repo on bitbucket. You have probably already visited this page, but I'll share just in case: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: Hi @psq, here are the results to the commands you asked for. `$ git remote -v`
origin  ssh://git@code.pruconnect.net:7999/pbuilddpas/dpas-portal-frontend.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@code.pruconnect.net:7999/pbuilddpas/dpas-portal-frontend.git (push)

`$ ls -al ~ | grep '\.ssh'`
drwx------    7 amijeetthakur  staff     224  9 Nov 13:35 .ssh

Comment: `$ ls -al ~/.ssh`
total 48
drwx------   7 amijeetthakur  staff   224  9 Nov 13:35 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 66 amijeetthakur  staff  2112  9 Nov 15:24 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 amijeetthakur  staff  6148  9 Nov 13:16 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@  1 amijeetthakur  staff    87  9 Nov 13:39 config
-r--------   1 amijeetthakur  staff  2622  9 Nov 15:41 id_rsa
-r--------   1 amijeetthakur  staff   584  9 Nov 15:41 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 amijeetthakur  staff  1001  7 Nov 17:03 known_hosts

Comment: @AmijeetThakur I have run out of ideas. What does `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` report? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565700/how-to-specify-the-private-ssh-key-to-use-when-executing-shell-command-on-git

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding these two lines to the end of your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```bash
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Alternatively you can add them to your `~/.ssh/config` file either for all hosts or only to a specific one (change `*` to desired host):

```bash
Host *
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and finally found that MacOS update was the cause. The latest release disables SHA-1 hash algorithm which broke SSH.

I used below solution:

1. Locate into your /ssh/config file

   ```
    sudo nano ~/.ssh/config
   ```
2. Add below code in:

   ```
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   ```
3. Type 'Control + X' to save your change, click 'y' to confirm your changes.