# Git: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh

Struggling to understand why git wont let me clone?

I am trying to clone via SSH, the key is added to my github but its failing?

```
git clone git@github.com:org/repo.git
```

Says:

```
\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Testing via:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Gives

```
Hi ...! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

My ssh key is saved in C:\Users\admin\.ssh\id_rsa.pub and has been added?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

Answer (score 1):

The comment did not address your question. For me this fix was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392010/7432276

In `~\.ssh\config` set the `Host` line to `Host *`. Not sure of the beauty of the answer but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and referring to the other answer! It solved my issue.