# cant git clone from my pc with gitlab behind traefik

Tags: git, docker, traefik, git-clone

here's my gitlab & traefik configuration

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitlab_web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.roger'
    container_name: gitlab-ce
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.roger'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab_local.rule=Host(`gitlab.roger`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab_roger.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.gitlab_roger.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.gitlab-ssh-roger.rule=HostSNI(`gitlab.roger`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.gitlab-ssh-roger.entrypoints=ssh"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.gitlab-ssh-roger.service=gitlab-ssh-roger"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.gitlab-ssh-roger.loadbalancer.server.port=22"
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - rudak_traefik_network

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - gitlab_web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./runner.toml:/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
    networks:
      - rudak_traefik_network
networks:
  rudak_traefik_network:
    external: true
```

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    command:
      - "--configfile=/etc/traefik/traefik_static.yaml"
    ports:
      - "22:22"
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik_static.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik_static.yaml:ro"
      - "./dynamic_conf.yaml:/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf.yaml:ro"
    networks:
      - rudak_traefik_network

networks:
  rudak_traefik_network:
    external: true
```

traefik_static.yaml

```yaml
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"
  ssh:
    address: ":22"
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: "/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf.yaml"
```

I have access to the gitlab web interface
I can access git clone from my different containers which are on the only rudak_traefik_network
I can git clone from my docker server too
my problem is that I can't access git clone from my remote pc

the traefik dashboard is all success with tcp router HostSNI(`gitlab.roger`) success too

the ssh key on my pc is correctly inserted in the gitlab interface and it works fine from any container, but I'm getting this

```bash
git clone git@gitlab.roger:roger/test-project.git
Cloning into 'test-project'...
git@gitlab.roger's password:
```

(my server's name is strangely roger, but I don't think that's the problem ^^.)

Comment: are you sure that port 22 is available on the docker host? It may mistakenly use the hosts sshd server instead proxying to the gitlab container.

Comment: I think that's what's happening, when I git clone * on port 22, I can't reach traefik because the host's ssh server catches the request beforehand and tries to process it. so I've tried changing the host's port 22 to 4567 to test it, but that doesn't work either, I can't reach traefik. from the host itself or inside my containers, no problem, but from the outside, impossible, ...for the moment.

Comment: Does cloning over HTTPS work?

Comment: yes, it works with http

Comment: Can you try and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your host machine. Look for the line that says `Port 22` and change it to `Port <some_other_port>`, e.g., `Port 4567`. And `sudo systemctl restart sshd`. Make sure you can SSH into your host with the new port (`ssh -p <some_other_port> user@your_server`). Then update your `git clone` command: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -p 22" git clone git@gitlab.roger:roger/test-project.git`.

Comment: From your local box, did you actually set to use the ssh key? like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/6336357 ?

Comment: What happens if you ssh into your gitlab: `ssh git@gitlab.roger` It should tell you who you are. If not, your SSH keys aren't set up correctly.

Comment: no, i've tried these techniques but i still get the same thing, it looks like my server is responding instead of passing me through traefik ssh