# Adding an SSH-key permanently in msysgit windows

Tags: git, ssh, github, msysgit

I am in a situation, where I need my msysgit to talk to github with different keys. However git bash insists on using the keyfile named id_rsa **ONLY**. If I do ssh -vT git@github.com I see only id_rsa being offered.

So whenever I need to use any other key I have to do all this,

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mygithubkey
git clone git@github.com:myaccount/myrepo.git
```

or rename `mygithubkey` to `id_rsa` whenever i need it backing up the original id_rsa to another file `anotherkey`

and of course it is a pain, especially because the command history is also different across the regular git bash.

Other answers in stackoverflow helped only to arrive at my above workaround. If I do

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mygithubkey
```

directly in my git bash, it says could not connect to ssh-agent. If I do

```
ssh-agent ssh-add ~/.ssh/mygithubkey
git pull
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

directly in my git bash, it says permission denied, it seems `ssh-add` did not really add the key permanently! And the added key is not offered while looking at the debug messages in verbose mode.

Is there anyway to permanently add a list of ssh keys to offer, when sshing into github? Im mostly a windows user today, so please be verbose in the answer.

Comment: Why do you need multiple keys?  One key should be all you ever need.

Comment: You are right, i can manage with just one key, but just as an academic question, could folks here attempt an answer??

Comment: It's possible, but a big pain in the ass and really not worth doing: http://help.github.com/multiple-ssh-keys/

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest to use a `~/.ssh/config` file similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419609/1127485). Something like:

```
Host github1
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mygithubkey

Host github2
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myothergithubkey
```

That way you could easily switch keys by typing either `ssh github1` or `ssh github2` to connect.

Comment: Where would that be on Windows?

Comment: The tilde (`~`) is a placeholder for the current user's home directory, i.e. what the combination of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` on Windows points to. Starting with Windows Vista this would be something like `C:\Users\<username>`, so the config file would be at `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\config`.