# Git SSH client for windows and wrong path for .ssh/config file

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I installed Git-1.7.9-preview20120201.exe, and when I try to access my repository via SSH it failed.

I investigated and found that if I run `SSH -T git@myrepo.com`, SSH doesn't load ~/.ssh/config where a custom port is defined.

When I try `SSH -F c:\users\tomas\.ssh\config git@myrepo.com` everything is OK.

I used Process Monitor and found that SSH is trying to find `\\\\.ssh\config` here `C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace\.ssh`.

Why?

How I can force it to use normal path? `%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\config`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found that windows msygit port store ssh config here `<installPath>\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config`

Comment: Maybe it is obvious to others, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me, an ssh newb; the "ssh\ssh_config" file/folder might not already exist.  I created it and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Mark_Eng - File already exists for me, timestamp is 2 years old, and I'm pretty sure I didn't manually make it...

Answer (score 50):

set the `HOME` environment variable pointing to `%USERPROFILE%` for ssh to pick it up. This usually seems to be the problem for many unix solutions that run on windows.

Fast access to set user env variables:

`Start > Type "env" > Select "Environmental variables for your account"`

Comment: This is actually the correct answer because the other one despite it works it just says something not completely true. That path is aimed at all users and it's not the only location where the config file may be stored. It can still be located in the user folder but the HOME must be correctly set for it to correctly work.