# System-wide SSH configuration file for Eclipse IDE on Windows

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, ssh

We are using the Eclipse IDE on Windows virtual machines running on Xen. On the other hand, we are using Gitolite to manage the Git repositories. They are mirrored across several servers using Gitolite's mirroring feature.

What I intend to do is to transparently switch the users to the backup server in case the master server is down.

To do so, my idea is to create a system-wide host alias in the SSH settings. On Linux for instance, I would use the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file with an entry like:

```
Host scms.box
    Hostname master-server
```

If ever master-server is down, I can then replace the hostname:

```
Host scms.box
    Hostname backup-server
```

The Eclipse IDE is reading the SSH settings from `~/.ssh/config` but this is user-specific (like on Linux).
I was wondering if there would be an equivalent to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there would be an equivalent to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on Windows?

As mentioned in "[Git SSH client for Windows and path for `.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632915/6309)"

```
 <installPath>\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config
```

If you [set `GIT_SHH`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Environment) to `<installPath>\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` (and the launch Eclipse), then Eclipse should also use the global ssh config.

Comment: This requires an additional software to be installed. Is there no internal feature to eGit/eclipse to handle it?

Comment: @fboule Not installed. Merely unzipped: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.3-64-bit.7z.exe

Comment: Ok but the point is this is yet another software to maintain (to update on bug fixes, security fixes, etc). This is acceptable when you have only one install but not when you are talking about the working environment of ~100 users.

Comment: @fboule this one is secure, you can download it without worries.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: it is not implemented in JGit. It only supports the "user" config file.

**Long answer**: I have been looking into the EGit/JGit source code. JGit is reading the SSH configuration and passing the object as argument to create the SSH session. However, JGit only supports the user config file.

Snippet of [`jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/OpenSshConfig.java`](https://github.com/spearce/jgit/blob/12e38d72758b486f19ccfa6c830d1ef95dfb1d11/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/OpenSshConfig.java#L78-L100):

```java
public static OpenSshConfig get(FS fs) {
    File home = fs.userHome();
    if (home == null)
        home = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile(); //$NON-NLS-1$

    final File config = new File(new File(home, ".ssh"), Constants.CONFIG); //$NON-NLS-1$
    final OpenSshConfig osc = new OpenSshConfig(home, config);
    osc.refresh();
    return osc;
}
```