# Cannot git pull from cmd window, but can on git bash

Tags: git

I'm receiving the below error when I try to git pull from the command window.

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   '[10.10.46.213]:2222'  to the list of known hosts. Permission denied
>   (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

However, on git bash window, I am able to do a git pull.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is configured differently under cmd and bash for some reason. At least in the part of key storage.

First of all, check environment PATH in cmd and in bash, check if the path to git binaries is really the same in both. If it is not the same, it may be that you have two separate bundles for git installed in two places using two different configs. In that case, either remove one and stick to the other in both shells, or configure them to use the same options/sshtools/paths.

If you have one single git client used in both shells, it can still be using different configurations. Often, git uses your 'home directory' for storing keys (i.e. folder %HOME%.ssh). Check if in cmd the %HOME% points to the same directory as $HOME in git bash. It may even be that you dont have %HOME% at all in the cmd. There's a bit more on it in this question [Git SSH client for windows and wrong path for .ssh/config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9513712/717732)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

This is what I did to fix it:

in CMD, echo %HOME%, nothing happened.
in Git bash, echo $HOME, C/ appeared

I fixed by adding an environment variable called HOME, value of %USERPROFILE%

I added %HOME% to PATH environment variable and this fixed it.

Comment: @user3814557: great, all good! actually, having HOME in PATH shouldn't be necceesary. If you have some time for testing, try removing it from PATH. Everything should still work. PATH is usually used for finding binaries, so if you don't have anything installed right at HOME location, you won't need it PATH.