# Git how to clone with SSH key, username

Tags: git, clone

I have the following and i need to clone the repository in either windows terminal command prompt or linux.

- **URL:** git@xxxxx.com:xxx/xxx/git
- **username:** xxx@xxx.in
- **SSH key:** ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yxxxxxxxxxxxx....xxx@xxx.in

I tried as :

```
git clone git@xxxxx.com:xxx/xxx/git
```

I get

```
Permission denied(public key)
Couldn't read from remote repository
```

Also tried to change the URL as:

```
git clone https://xxxxx.com:xxx/xxx/git
```

Comment: Have you added your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in your account profile (e.g. GitHub, BitBucket)?

Comment: We dont have access to the account profile...The details are shared from the client and we just need to clone our code into their github

Answer (score 253):

Always coming late to answer anything, it may be possible that you have more than one ssh keys and if not specified git will try to use `id_rsa` but if you need a different one you could use

```sh
git clone git@provider.com:userName/projectName.git --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/location/to/private_ssh_key"
```

This way it will apply this config and use a key different than `id_rsa` before actually fetching any data from the git repository.

subsequent `fetch` or `push` will use the specified key to authenticate for the cloned repository.

Hope this is helpful to anyone.

Comment: But it makes problems with recursive submodules

Comment: after cloning, initializing submodules does not work. is there any workaround?

Comment: well, the problem with sub-module is a bit different, that the one I was initially trying to tackle, but basically you would need to override the `.git/config` file inside of each submodule and correct the sshCommand to whatever the submodule requires.
you may get a better explanation reading the documentation here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_configuration_file

Comment: You can add this as a function to your ~/.profile and have git "aliases" specific for each repo/organization. 

`function git-company(){git ${@:1} --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/company_private_key"}`
This allows use of git-company instead of git for repos that need company_private_key. All parameters are being passed transparently.

Comment: I've found out (this is maybe specific to BitBucket) that the repo cannot be private in order to clone it even if the private SSH key is used.

Comment: This asks me to enter the passphrase every time I do `git pull`. Is there a way for the ssh agent to remember this key? When I run `ssh-add -l` I see it there among other keys. But only the one that's at the top won't request the passphrase every time. All others will. I use `pwsh` on Win.

Answer (score 65):

I suggest that you follow those steps:

## Step 1: Check for existing SSH keys

`$> ls -al ~/.ssh`

Do you see any files named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`?

If yes go to Step 3

If no, you need to generate them

## Step 2: Generate a new SSH key

`$> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourEmail"`

Add your SSH key to the ssh-agent

`$> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

`$> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

## Step 3.1: Add the SSH key to your GIT account.

Get your public key

`$> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Go to your GIT Account Settings (your profile picture in the upper right corner) -> Settings -> SSH and GPG keys -> New SSH key

Then  paste the content of your public key into SSH keys

## Step 3.2: Force SSH Client To Use Given Private Key

This is an alternative solution when you can't set keys on your Git account

`$> sudo nano ~/.ssh/config`

Then change this line

`IdentityFile <yourPrivateKey>`

## Step 4: Clone the project

`$> git clone git@xxxxx.com:xxx/xxx/git`

Comment: Is there alternate way to Step3 , cause we dont have access to GIT account, having only the specified details from my question , i guess i cant access the Git account... Also i have the ssh key content (i guess its id_rsa.pub contents)....so i created a folder, with the file name id_rsa.pub and pasted the contents i have...

Comment: When you tape in a command `cat ~/.ssh/config` Do you see `IdentityFile` line?

Comment: Here is the structure, i have a folder in my windows local drive as : C/Users/me/Test/.ssh  in My ssh folder , i have .id_rsa file,  and i when i type cat ~/.ssh/config i get no such file

Comment: @Sachins I updated my answer: See *Step 3.2: Force SSH Client To Use Given Private Key*

Comment: @Sachins Since you're working on Windows take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513712/git-ssh-client-for-windows-and-wrong-path-for-ssh-config-file

Comment: What does config file contain? by the way im running all these commands in cygwin terminal or babun and since i dont have config file, i get file not found, Also in the 1st step itself, when i do ls -al ~/.ssh i dont see id_rsa, even though  they physically exist in the folder

Comment: Please note that while `id_rsa` is the default given to ssh keys, they *need not* be named this.

Comment: This does not start where the question is located. The user already has an ssh key provided. You haven't really answered his question.

Comment: If `~/.ssh/config` is empty, simply adding `IdentityFile id_rsa` will not work, you need the syntax, for ex: `Host github.com` `User git` `Hostname github.com`
  `IdentityFile id_rsa` ... [reference](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/) I'd edit the answer but Edit queue is full...

Comment: Step 3.2 super thanks. Note; it's important to specify correct host. For instance `Host ssh.dev.azure.com `

Answer (score 9):

## test ssh with GitHub to get actionable feedback.

in the command line run `ssh -T git@github.com` 
(see https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)

---

if that works,  bother with git next. but likely there will, be your issue.

to clone, THEN use `git clone git@github.com:$USERNAME/$REPONAME.git`

Comment: Doesn't really address the question as asked.

Answer (score -13):

To clone source code without using ssh, we can use http url with following format:

`http://usernameWITHOUTdomain:password@the_rest_httpURL`

ex: `http://myname:password@192.110.110.10/projectname/project.git`

Comment: This is using http, not ssh.

Comment: Sure, but you said "To clone source code with Git using ssh", which is not what the example does.

Comment: This does not follow ssh protocol - not a solution

Comment: Just another issue with this: sometimes reverse proxy on the server side has a timeout. For large repositories, GIT server takes much longer than this timeout value to generate initial response. This makes virtually impossible to clone repository via HTTP. That's why we have to fallback to using SSH instead.