# Git: how to set not standard private SSH key path for a given repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-bash

I have a problem pushing to my Gitlab account via SSH, since I moved the key pair in the different folder.

Consequently after pushing in the remote I got an "access denied" error, which I assume is connected to the fact that ssh tries to use standard id_rsa in .ssh folder.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714882/git-how-to-clone-with-ssh-key-username), I found a way to clone repo using non-standard path to the private SSH key. Now I want to make it default for a given repo using (from [Git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand)):

```
git config core.sshCommand='ssh -i path/to/the/key/privatkeyfilename'
```

I get and error:

```
invalid key: core.sshCommand=ssh -i path/to/the/key/privatkeyfilename
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you remove `=`. You could use following correction.

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i path/to/the/key/privatkeyfilename'
```

Comment: now command seems to work (no error appeared). But when pushing I get "Warning: Identity file path/to/the/key/privatkeyfilename not accessible: No such file or directory." I checked multiple times the path seems fine. I use the path form of 'c/folder1/folder2/nameofthekeyfile'.

Comment: Does your path `path/to/the/key/privatkeyfilename` exist? You should check it again.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was that when you type the path all the way from,for example,  c: drive it should be: 
'/c/folder1/folder2/keyfilename' and not 'c/folder1/folder2/keyfilename'. Thank you very much :).

Comment: I am glad that you have solved your problem. Could you upvote my answer?

Comment: I did. It says that I have not enough reputation for my upvote to be displayed :(

Comment: The `=` is used in the `-c` option, see answer that shows how to clone a repo passing the ssh key to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412112/2932052