# On windows, could not create directory '/home/<username>/.ssh'

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, git-bash

To configure git on windows with gitbash, (as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-windows)):

- I generated a ssh key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` at `/c/Users/my-username/.ssh`.
- then, added the ssh key to ssh-agent with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

The problem is now, every-time I try to connect to github via ssh, there is an error message with a reference to a wrong location:

```
Could not create directory '/home/my-username/.ssh'.
```

**How to fix this?**

Things I tried:

- I checked [in the env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21451748/2112538) and in `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but didn't find anything…
- And I [set the HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513712/git-ssh-client-for-windows-and-wrong-path-for-ssh-config-file/21451748#21451748) pointing to %USERPROFILE% for ssh to pick it up with `setx HOME %USERPROFILE%`.
- In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/736063/264961), someone having the same problem with cygwin, modified a file in cygwin to fix the problem. Is there something similar in my case?

Comment: Show us the actual values of `HOME` and `USERPROFILE` from the same environment where you are running `ssh`.

Comment: @tripleee sure, from gitbash, how can I get those variable?

Comment: Just type "SET" in cmd

Comment: @Christoph bash: SET: command not found

Comment: @tripleee with `env` I read `HOME=/c/Users/my-username` and `USERPROFILE=C:\Users\my-username`

Comment: If you are using Bash, I'm not sure the instructions you are attempting to follow are correct. Does `HOME='%USERPROFILE%'` do anything for you? If you just set it on the prompt, the setting will be lost when you exit that prompt, so you can play around with different things without committing to anything yet (I think ... Windows might make that murkier too).

Comment: Set is for windows cmd, not unix/linux Shell. I use windows 8.

Comment: @tripleee I did `setx HOME %USERPROFILE%` which set the global variable permanently. is that right?

Comment: I thought you were saying you are using Bash, not `cmd`? I don't pretend to know anything about Windows really anyway.

Comment: Yes I use gitbash. I don't know anything about windows either… that's the problem