# Git for Windows: Cannot add host to known_hosts. Wrong user directory

Tags: windows, git, ssh

Git for Windows worked fine with SSH authentication. However, the SSH sever signature has changed. I deleted the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file in the hope that ssh will recreate it.
However, when I try to push to the remote via SSH, I get the following message:

Let's assume my Windows username is "abc".

```
$ git push
 Could not create directory '/home/abc/.ssh' (No such file or directory).
 Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/abc/.ssh/known_hosts).
 git@my_bitbucket.hu: Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

On Windows I don't have the /home/abc directory. $HOME is set to "/c/Users/abc".
How can I fix this? I tried several solutions from [On windows, could not create directory '/home/<username>/.ssh'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053696/on-windows-could-not-create-directory-home-username-ssh), but nothing worked.

In the Wondows CMD %HOME% and %USERPROFILE% are set to "/c/Users/abc". Why is ssh trying to touch the file under "/home/abc/.ssh"?

Comment: Find out (a) which ssh program you're using on Windows (there's more than one) and (b) how to configure it. Git just runs ssh; you can configure *Git* to select *which* ssh to run using Git's `core.sshCommand` setting, in case one works and another doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same from a CMD session (no git bash), with:

- `%HOME%` and `%USERPROFILE%` are set to "C:\Users\abc"
- `%PATH%` set to:

  ```
  set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"
  set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
  ```
- no SSH environment variable set ( check with `set|grep -i ssh`)

Then try again, from that same CMD session, again without bash.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. Still the same problems. It still tries to access /home/abc/.ssh. I completely reinstalled git but it didn't help either.

Comment: @GNA What does `git remote -v` returns, when executed from the root folder of your repository?

Comment: it returns the address of the project on the bitbucket server: Something like: git@my_server.com:1234/my/project. I hate this Windows pain... Never actually had any problems with Linux.. but on Windows everything breaks just overnight.

Comment: @GNA Fo you see home defined anywhere in `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope | grep home`?

Comment: Nope. No reference to /home

Comment: @GNA What about `set` (to list environment variables)?

Comment: I now had time to look back. So even set | grep "home" didn't result in anything. There is also no reference to the home directory. The issue literally started from one moment to the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250406/discussion-between-vonc-and-gna).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at work and the chat is blocked here -_-.