# Specifying private key file for Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

When I want to use a specific private key file for a single git operation, apparently I have to change the GIT_SSH environment variable. However, I cannot just set it to
`C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -i D:\repo\key`.

The [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) confirms this:

> To pass options to the program that you want to list in GIT_SSH you
>   will need to wrap the program and options into a shell script, then
>   set GIT_SSH to refer to the shell script.

So, how do I do this? What is a "shell script" in this case? A batch file? A file with `#!bash`? Neither way works, both give me:

```
error: cannot spawn "D:\repo\test.bat": No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

With the .sh file I get the same error, just with a different filename of course. There is a bash in msysgit and it is in my PATH, but git does not seem to understand the shebang. I also tried to convert the path to an msys-style path (`/d/repo/test.sh`), but git still says "No such file or directory". When I run `bash` and paste the exact same path, it is executed.

Comment: What exact operation is it? Do you interact with another host or with the same host but different username?

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:...`

Comment: it's still not clear. You want to perform `git clone` with different keys?

Comment: Yes. And `push` and `pull` and you name it.

Comment: I used a different method (set `HOME`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching between multiple ssh keys in Git on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672975/switching-between-multiple-ssh-keys-in-git-on-windows)