# "git push" updates remote with global user name evenif local user name is set

Tags: linux, git

I have set the local user config using following command,

```
git config user.name "Ankur Tank"
git config user.email "ankur.tank@example.com"
```

`git config --global` is set for different user.

When I do git push, I see it is being pushed with global user name and email id.

How can I override global username and email? Is it possible ?
For `git commit --author < >` is possible but `git push --author < >` not available.

Any suggestions/pointer ?

**Edit:**
`.git/config` in my repo shows local user name what i have set. Even when i commit it takes local user name but for `git push` it take global user name and email.

Comment: What does the .git/config look like for the repo?

Comment: did you set the local user settings while you are inside the local repo?

Comment: @Rob: Updated description.

Comment: @Ammadu : Yes I had set local user setting while I was inside local repo. And then I copied the whole folder to other path and the `.git/config` shows local user name and email.

Comment: The local user/email takes higher precedence than global settings. I just checked it in my configuration. It works perfectly fine. Either you are missing something or you are using an ancient version of git.

Comment: When you `git log` , which author appears ? You might have committed under your global user and setup the local config after (push is for authentication, not ownership of commit)

Comment: Please see here for the difference between a committer and an author in Git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git - this might be what you're seeing here.

Comment: @positron : my git version is `git version 1.9.1`, I might be missing something but i don't know what. :(

Comment: @topheman When I `git log`, I see my name(local user config), But when I do `git push` It pushes with global user name. :(

Comment: @nwinkler: But when I `git log` I see local username(local user config), even `git log --pretty='%cn' -n1 HEAD` shows my name i.e. local username. So I assume in my case committer and an author is same, isn't it ?

Comment: I think i found the cause, not sure though, I didn't mention but we are using ssh keys. SSH key stored is created for another user..does that create problem? Because temporarily i changed the `git config --global user.name <myname>` and `git config --global user.email <my email>` but still it show previous user while I do `git push origin` Now only difference is key. I will try to change it temporarily and see if that some effect.

Answer (score 1):

After testing trying various combination, finally I found that root cause was ssh key. I followed steps in the another question [Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client/2419609#2419609) , I followed steps mentioned by Wahib Haq.

Here are steps
1. # ssh-agent bash
2. # ssh-add /path.to/private/key
   To list added ssh private key we
3. # ssh-add -l

After that when I do `git push` it takes local config and update goes in my name.