# How to use two ssh on the same server

Tags: ssh, server

I have ssh and I've added it to server and git. But I also want to add another ssh key to the same server. Is this possible and how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: just add another row into your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, you need to add additional public keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. That said, the password needs to correspond to the key you're using. You can specify this key like so: `ssh -i /path/to/chosen/key user@server`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client?rq=1) for more info/examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many new keys as you want simply adding new lines in the 
`.ssh/authorized_keys` file with the public keys.

Comment: But when I connect to server and it asks for password, will I be able to enter one of the two passwords of the two ssh keys?

Comment: I added the second key to the authorized_keys but when I try to connect to server and enter password for the new ssh key, it returns error message for invalid password.

Comment: Check that you have added the public key to the user in the remote server that you want to connect. For instance, if you want to connect to the user _git_ in the server _remote_ you have to place your public key in the `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and use `ssh git@remote` to connect