# SSH Key issue for Gitlab

Tags: ssh, key, gitlab

I was trying to install Gitlab client and when it asked to create a new Private and public key, instead of selcting default location, I selected a custom folder. Now I am not sure how to get it back to default location so I dont need to do more configurations. 
If there is no way I can revert back, i know I need to config my ~/.ssh/config but where  is this file I am not sure about that?
Can someone please guide me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `~/.ssh/config` file by `nano ~/.ssh/config` or else (by default this file does not exist). Then configure as you like

```
Host github.com
User git
Hostname <e.g. github.com>
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile <file-location, e.g. ~/.ssh/custom>
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135590/4133798)