# Multiple ssh access types from a given user1/client to the same user2/server

Tags: ssh, authorization, ssh-keys, bazaar

I want to access from one user/client combination (say, `user1@cl`) to a user/server combination (say, `user2@srv`) via ssh, with two different types of Access:

1. Access type #1 would be restricted to interactions with a bazaar repository.
   For this, I added a line (#1) in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` like

   ```
   command="bzr serve --inet --directory=/repodir --allow-writes",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa ... user1@cl
   ```
2. Access type #2 would be a login shell.
   For this, I added a "usual" line (#2) in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` like

   ```
   ssh-rsa ... user1@cl
   ```

As I understand, and as I tested, both lines cannot be used simultaneously.
I.e., if line #1 appears first in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then I would be able to interact with the bzr repo, but I will not be able to do

```
[user1@cl]$ ssh user2@srv
```

If line #2 appears first in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then I would be able to do `ssh`, but any `bzr` operation gives

```
bzr: ERROR: Not a branch ...
```

**Is there any way to work this out?**

I am using RHEL7, but I guess this is not important.

Related posts (but not addressing my case, as I understand):

[Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client)

https://serverfault.com/questions/142997/what-options-can-be-put-into-a-ssh-authorized-keys-file

https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1962/how-can-multiple-private-keys-be-used-with-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, with two different key pairs (say, pair 1 for `bzr` and pair 2 for `ssh` login).
I added the corresponding lines in `~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
The private key 1 was stored in file `id_rsa` (which is read by default), 
and the private key 2 was stored in file `id_rsa_ssh`.

Then, `bzr` was working normally, and for logging in I use

```
[user1@cl]$ ssh -i id_rsa_ssh user2@srv
```

which indicates using an alternative identity.