# working on two github accounts

Tags: git, github

I have two git hub accounts. I am Windows user and I use git bash as the client.I am working on a project. I can push my project to first github account. But when I try to push second one it says there is no permission.

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to <secondUser>/<repo>.git denied to <firstUser>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<secondUser>/<repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Can any one suggest a way to push the project to second account.

Comment: [See how you can manage multiple SSH key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135590/4133798)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/). In the config file(usually `~/.ssh/config`) you can define multiple alias for multiple accounts like this(for instance in Linux):

```
Host first_name 
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_first_name

Host second_name 
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_second_name
```

Under the directory of the repository in `./.git/config` you can set like this:

```
[remote "first_account"]
    url = git@first_name:[your_first_github_name]/[repository_name].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/first_name/*
[remote "second_account"]
    url = git@second_name:[your_second_github_name]/[repository_name].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/second_name/*
```

While pushing you can do this:

```
git push first_account master:master
git push second_account master:second_master
```

You can apply this mechanism to the windows scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Generate SSH key on your pc, add this ssh key in your both account.
Then it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But when I was going to add to second account, it says key is already in use.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574 her I found a complete answer