# Gitea - SSH Auth ok but can't push to remote

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, gitea

My Gitea version is 1.2.3 and it's install on a gentoo dedicated server.
I created my SSH key on another dedicated server with my user (not the root one).

On the Gitea GUI, I created an Organization and a repo for that organization, my gitea user is the owner of all of that (not the root account)

When I go to [Organization]/ [MyRepo] > Settings > Deploy keys, I add the ssh key of my remote user.
Gitea add that key to the authorized_key file in the .ssh git user (git user is the user for gitea)

From my remote, when I tried that :

```
ssh git@[gitea_server_ip]
```

I've got this message :

```
Hi there, You've successfully authenticated, but Gitea does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gitea under another user.
```

So SSH work well, but when I tried a push or clone, I get that :

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer :

```
Gitea: Key permission denied  
Cannot push with deployment key: 5 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

It's seems to be a gitea authentication problem but I don't find the answer, thanks.

Comment: AFAIU your ssh key for pushing must be user key, not deployment key. See https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/938

Comment: Ok so what should I use ? Because I generated the key with my remote user and use it for the deploy key, this is the wrong way ? Thanks for your help

Comment: I found the following info about deploy keys for Github ([1](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys), [2](https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115)) and [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys). I think it's similar with gogs/gitea — you need to create new or use existing user key, add its public key to gitea account and reconfigure ssh to use its private key to connect to the server.

Comment: In what you tell to do I had already do all of that except the part "reconfigure ssh to use its private key to connect to the server", what do you mean exactly ? Because I can't give private key to the other server, isn't it ?

Comment: You now have 2 ssh keypairs — user key and deploy key. You need to [configure ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2419566/7976758) to allow git to use one or the other. Of course you don't publish your private keys.

Comment: I finally find a solution but it's seems to be a weird way. 
Instead of putting the key to the organization project, I put it to my gitea user, wich his owner of organization and the project, and it's work. So I think I will create a user for the server, maybe it's the most proper way. Thanks a lot for your help, all your links help me to find that.

Answer (score 0):

This message comes if you use a deployment key without write access or the write option is not finnish in implementation for your gitea version. I get this error:

`Gitea: Key permission denied
Cannot push with deployment key: 14
fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

If this account only has read permissions.

You may use the standard ssh auth: < gitea:port >/user/settings/keys
Add your public key an then it should work.

Comment: what's the "standard ssh auth"?

Comment: standard ssh autentication using autorised_keys file like gitea does also