# Gitea: Unauthorized on push and pull

Tags: git, ssh, gitea

Gitea is setup through a helm chart on a Kubernetes cluster.
As in [Gitea - SSH Auth ok but can't push to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170226/gitea-ssh-auth-ok-but-cant-push-to-remote), SSH Auth works fine with the `git` user.
HTTPS connections also work fine.

But when I try to push or pull via SSH,
I get:

```
Gitea: Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 1):

If you do see the "`Hi there, You've successfully authenticated, but Gitea does not provide shell access.`" with `ssh -Tv git@your.Gitea`, that means you actually does not "have the correct access rights".

Or that you have made a small mistake in the repository URL (lowercase/upercase, or typo). That would address the second part of the error message ("`the repository [does not] exists`")

---

The [OP xeruf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6723250/xeruf) points in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204170/gitea-unauthorized-on-push-and-pull/73219322#comment131408416_73219322) to [`metallb-gitea.yaml`](https://open.greenhost.net/xeruf/stackspout/-/blob/main/basic/apps/code/metallb-gitea.yaml):

```yaml
# https://metallb.org/usage/
#apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gitea-ssh
  namespace: stackspout
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: "share-ipv4"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "${ip_address}"
  ports:
    - name: ssh
      protocol: TCP
      port: 22
      targetPort: 22
  selector:
    app: gitea
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I get. I have an ssh key in my account, and double-checked the repo name :/

Comment: @xeruf Is this an on-premise Gitea instance? Could an admin check the logs?

Comment: I am the admin :) as said, running on Kubernetes, from the official helm chart. Unfortunately, I get absolutely no logs upon performing any of these actions.

Comment: Even after setting the log.LEVEL to trace :/

Comment: @xeruf So a connection issue then: the SSH query never reaches the pod where Gitea resides. Is ingress enabled? (https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/#server-defaults). Is it configured properly? (as in https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/issues/303)

Comment: Honestly, I am very confused. Why do I get the successful authentication via SSH but not when using git? Furthermore, `Gitea: Unauthorized` suggests to me that it does reach gitea. But I also see nothing in the logs anywhere. Also asked in https://open.greenhost.net/stackspin/stackspin/-/issues/1364 now.

Comment: @xeruf If this related to https://open.greenhost.net/stackspin/stackspin/-/issues/1310? Because 1364 just got closed.

Comment: got it working after all, see https://open.greenhost.net/xeruf/stackspout/-/blob/main/basic/apps/code/metallb-gitea.yaml :)

Comment: @xeruf Great, well done! What did you do to make it work?

Comment: @xeruf I have included your comment and link in the answer for more visibility.