# Multiple ssh keys

Tags: git, ssh

Well, I have seen answers in the ssh post of having multiple private key, but I haven't gain enough reputations to add any comment so I have to write a new question (sorry about that).

In the post, the answer given is the config file to direct(point to) each host/username to the private key file that it suppose to use but is there any way to have a default private key file for general use, then some others private key file for some specific use?

For example, I use my school gitlab repository so I use one specific private key for it, then I have accounts on gitlab, github .... and others ssh connections that use the same private key (but different from the school one, of course).

So, is there a way to config a default private key so should it failed to use the specific key it will use the default or I have to configure everything manually?

Comment: The answer to the question for the multiple private key is from this post, mine was to ask an additionnal question to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client

Comment: Yes you can have multiple keys. I use the ssh config file to achieve it. There are tutorials online on this subject.

Comment: I think default key is chosen by using the wildcard match `*` in the host property.

Comment: Yeah, I know thanks, but my question is about how to make it that there is a default private key so that when you dont specified the server or username, this « default » will be use instead of add names of every server one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to have a default private key file for general use, then some others private key file for some specific use?

You define in your ~/.ssh/config file an entry `Host *`

```
Host h1
   ...

Host *
   IdentityFile /my/default/ssh/key
```

Make sure to define it *last* (or you would [need to add exclusion patterns](https://superuser.com/a/859719/141)).