# git push ssh broken pipe error / http curl ssl read error

Tags: github, ssh, https, git-push

I am using MAC OS Yosemite and I want to push a 17 MB file to my github-Account. I tried both git over ssh and over https and both did not work.
`GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin master` returns as last 6 lines:

```
Counting objects: 243, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.30.253.113 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Searching for solutions to my problem I started to set TCPKeepAlive, ServerAlive, ClientAlive parameters in the various config scripts ending up with:
In `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
   PubKeyAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ServerAliveInterval 300
   TCPKeepAlive no
   #ServerAliveCountMax 2400
```

In `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.89 2013/02/06 00:20:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# See sshd_config(5) for details on setting the Port and Listen values on Mac OS X
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords both PasswordAuthentication and
# ChallengeResponseAuthentication must be set to "no".
#PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# Also, PAM will deny null passwords by default.  If you need to allow
# null passwords, add the " nullok" option to the end of the
# securityserver.so line in /etc/pam.d/sshd.
#UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#XauthLocation xauth # Default is to search $PATH (set by launchd(8)).  It is recommended that a full path be provided.
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox      # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth

Host *
ClientAliveCountMax 4
ClientAliveInterval 600
```

Still, adding the ClientAlive parameters to `/etc/sshd_config` and ServerAlive parameters to `~/.ssh/config` could not resolve my problem. I restarted the sshd service by using:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

and `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

`ssh -T git@github.com` returns:
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

So, then I tried to change to git over https with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<my username>/<my repo>
```

and setting the postBuffer size to 30MB:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 30M
```

And then GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin master returns:

```
...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* NTLM-proxy picked AND auth done set, clear picked!
* Hostname github.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.253.113...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.113) port 443 (#1)
* SSL re-using session ID
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: github.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
...
Host: github.com
Authorization: Basic Z3JvMW06YSooYitjKT1hKmIrYSpjTUc5MQ==
User-Agent: git/2.14.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-receive-pack-result
Content-Length: 57811865

* SSLRead() return error -9820
* Closing connection 1
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9820
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

So I do not know how I can upload my file, via ssh or https. Therefore, I would be glad if someone could suggest to me what I could try to be able upload my file successfully to Github. Even better if someone could tell me the root cause to my problem and a solution to it. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me in the context of pushing my repo to github. I added *IPQoS=throughput* to ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Did you add IPQoS=throughput to a specific host? Did not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as pointed out by @VonC, the `packet_write_issue` from pushing over ssh and the `SSLRead() return error` from pushing via https were caused by a bad internet connection. 
In my case, I improved the network connection by plugging the internet cable directly into the router and not through the wall connections we have at home. Finally, this allowed me to upload my files to github.com.

Comment: Connecting to AWS over ssh worked just fine and therefore, I did not think that directly connecting my internet cables to the router would have such an impact.  It would therefore be interested to know if there is a terminal command to retrieve a network metric that tells one if the connection is good enough to upload your data to a remote repository.

Comment: Great, well done. +1. I have included in my answer the link I mentioned in the comment for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC: I think it would be good if you could change `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` in your answer, as otherwise an invalid key format error occurs in future git pushes, as pointed out in [SSH Error: invalid key format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328446/id-rsa-pub-file-ssh-error-invalid-format?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 4):

First, sshd is for configuring the ssh daemon, on the server side, which you are not (you are a client)

Second, your config should not use github.com as an Host entry.
Use a custom key like mygithub.
And add `User git` and `HostName github.com` in that section.

Your `~/.ssh/config` should then be:

```
Host mygithub
   HostName github.com
   PubKeyAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ServerAliveInterval 300
   TCPKeepAlive no
   #ServerAliveCountMax 2400
   User git
```

Then change your URL:

```
git remote set-url origin mygithub:MyAccount/MyRepo.git
```

And try again.

If the issue persists, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262847/6309), it is a network issue, and the OP confirms.

Comment: Ok, so I undid the changes to the sshd file. Now I am unsure about the custom key. If I take your example and just enter mygithub for my key and then change the URL as you suggested, then I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname mygithub: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. So I changed the first line to: `Host git@github.com` and I added `User git` on the second line. But this still gives me the same error. So, I would be glad if you could clarify your point about using the custom key.

Comment: @mgross I have edited the answer to include the `~/.ssh/config` file: you will then be able to resolve '`mygithub`'

Comment: This is what I did in the first place and I tried it again now by copying your ~/.ssh/config to be sure. Then I entered: `git remote set-url origin mygithub:<MyUserName>/<MyRepoName>.git`. And yet again, I get the error that `mygithub` cannot be resolved. The output of `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin master` further states that I should make sure to have the correct access rights and the repository exists. And I am sure that the repo exists; I copied the link from github.com. I changed access rights from `644` to `600` for the config file, but that did not change anything.

Comment: @mgross What does `ssh -T mygithub` returns? (done with the same accoutn than the one with ~/.ssh/config)

Comment: It returns: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname mygithub: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: @mgross Right! `HostName github.com` was missing! I have edited the answer.

Comment: @mgross See as an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49599523/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063480/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48248215/6309.

Comment: Ok, so now `ssh -T mygithub` returns: `Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` But the push still leads to the packet_write_wait broken pipe error.

Comment: @mgross So... that leaves you with an internet connection issue, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262847/6309.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue while connected to office internet. After couple of tries, switched to personal internet and executed "git push". This worked as expected.

If you are noticing below error while pushing the code to git, try switching network.

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 0.0.0.0 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```