# git config how use 2 username on same server

Tags: git, github, gitlab

i want to use 2 diferent username on same server gitlab.com
this is my actual config file :

```
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User username1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.username1
    IdentitiesOnly yes


Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User username2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.username2
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

if i push code in first account, working
if i try to push code in second account not working (because use key of first account)
working only for first position account on config file.

how i can use both account without this problems ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `Host` to make it uique:

```
Host username1.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User username1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.username1
    IdentitiesOnly yes


Host username2.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User username2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.username2
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

then change the host names in your local git repository:

```
user1/project>git remote -v 
origin git@gitlab.com/... (fetch)
origin git@gitlab.com/... (push)

user1/project>git remote remove origin
user1/project>git remote add origin git@username1.gitlab.com/...
```

Of cause a project alias instead of the user name will do too...

Comment: how i can do this with ssh link ? git@gitlab.com:usename/video-app.git because in this way not working git@username.gitlab.com:usename/video-app.git

Comment: @BelloDaniel what does "not working" mean? did you use the same `Host` in your `.ssh/config` and the repositoty URI (like `username**1**.gitlab.com`)?