# Managing multiple GIT ssh keys

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab, repository

Having some issues with maintaining too many SSH keys in the same computer lately.

- I have created two SSH keys in my computer for UserA(Company) and UserB(Personal). Both the ID's are created using different email ID
- I am able to pull and push the code changes for UserA

But UserB is where I face trouble to push my code.

- I am able to pull the code for UserB(Where repo is different than UserA)
- While pushing the code I get the following error

  `ERROR: Permission to UserB/xxxxxx.git denied to UserA.`

  ````
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists. ```
  ````

Feel bit strange to me. Can someone help me this ?

Comment: The answers for github and gitlab are (at least potentially) different here - pick one tag, not both!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!

Created Gitconfig for personal and work using the following link,

https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ssh-keys-with-multiple-github-accounts-c67db56f191e

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Git 2.3.0 you can use below command

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i private_key_file' git clone user@host:repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have the problem of too many keys stored in the ssh-agent.
Then the server refuses the connection after it offering too many keys.

This can be solved by force ssh to use only one specific key.

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o IdentityAgent=none -i private_key_file' git <cmd>
```