# Can I conect my GitLab and Github accounts in Visual Studio Code at the same time?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I have a Gitlab account for my job and I use my Github account for my personal purposes.

Can I connect the two accounts in Visual Studio Code and choose where to save the codes?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added a second remote to your Git repo ([`git remote add ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem)), you can, from VSCode, use Push to in order to chose where you want to push a repository.

But if you issue is about pushing to GitLab for one repository, and GitHub for another, you don't have to do anything: each one will use (for HTTPS URL) their respective credentials. VSCode will simply push to `origin`, as it does by default.

For SSH URL, you can [use separate keys](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) in [your `~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419609/6309), to differentiate the remote authentication.