# Have anyone used multiple SSH keys with VSCode Dev Containers?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, devcontainer

Context:
I use multiple accounts with the same host in my SSH config file, so I use aliases.
From [Best way to use multiple SSH private keys on one client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38454037/20231727)

From `.ssh/config`:

```
# Company account
Host company
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_company

# Personal account
Host personal
HostName github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

And I have started using [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) which [shares ssh credentials with the host](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container).

Problem:

When I try to use git on the remote container, it doesn't resolve the host since it's not importing the ssh configuration file, it's only importing the `.gitconfig` file.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

You can add your local ssh config file using a mount: see https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount